# Should we allow question and answer bodies to be written in Spanish?

Tags: discusión

The following question was asked in Spanish: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre tú, usted y vos?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/7/10)

This SE is oriented to learning and improving the Spanish language, so it doesn't seem that inappropriate, however, I was wondering what everyone else thinks (and also what is done in another language usage SE, if there is one)

Comment: It also has a Spanish tag, [tag:seleccion-de-palabras]. Should we make the tags English or Spanish?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing that. Tags should definitely be in English IMO

Comment: Created a [separate question](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-tags-be-in-english-spanish-or-both) about tags.

Comment: For reference, take a look at what the French.SE is doing: http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-sit

Comment: @BryanDenny take statistics for reference: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage  clearly french beta is not as successfully to be followed as an example

Answer (score 20):

Like we did in other sites, allow **both**.

- **English** must be there because it's the StackExchange sites' language.
- **Spanish** must be there as well, since this SE site is about Spanish.

There's no reason to choose only one of those two.

Comment: I can only vote this up once! )-:

Comment: Ahah thank you :D

Comment: If it's 100% in Spanish I'm sure I won't be able to help on some questions. If all L&U sites are 100% in their own language I won't even be able to participate in the German and French ones, let alone the Japanese SE (where I was offered pro-tem mod) and the Georgian language one I just proposed!

Comment: @Alenanno I think all languages should be allowed. There are, for example, Chinese people eager to learn Spanish. But they aren't good at English. How should they ask then?

Comment: @aminabzz I'm not the one you should ask that question.

Answer (score 17):

There are other language sites here, which I think have set a precedent, such as [Japanese L&U](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) and [German L&U](https://german.stackexchange.com/).

Both sites [allow](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/was-ist-das-dass-fur-ein-ding-was-du-nicht-willst-dass-man-dir-tu) [questions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2979/when-would-one-use-im-and-am-rather-than-in-dem-and-an-dem) [in both](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/when-writing-for-general-public-is-there-a-general-guideline-for-selecting-kanj) [English and the site language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/%E3%80%8C%E9%9B%A8%E3%81%8C%E9%99%8D%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%9C%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8C%E3%81%9C%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6). That seems to indicate that questions in either language should be acceptable. Generally, the answers are in the same language as the question, but that's not always true.

Tags on those sites are always in English. That means we should replace our [seleccion-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seleccion-de-palabras) tag with [word-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice)

EDIT: [The French L&U site](https://french.stackexchange.com/) [took a different stance on this](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-sit). If you look at the front page, you'll see that the vast majority of questions are in French, and that the tags are also in French.

Comment: I clicked those links and in the Japanese SE did not see any question in the frontpage fully in Japanese. I did see them in the German site, but 50% is not enough to use as a correct decision IMO (I'm not saying I disagree with having questions and answers in Spanish yet though)

Comment: It does seem like this is an issue that all the SE language sites should have a common stance on.

Comment: See French.SE too: http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-sit

Comment: @JuanManuel Click the fourth link in the second paragraph. The questions and answers are entirely in Japanese.

Comment: It's not an issue however most of the users coming from the stack exchange network are English speakers, I don't know a bit of Japanese and trust me if the JP SO was in Japanese I wouldn't even open it, if is in English there is a fairly bigger chance that I will take a look at it.

Comment: Saw it, thanks.

Comment: Look at beta statistics, I wouldn't take french beta as a role model.

Comment: @Rafael.IT French.SE had about 135 questions in the first 8 days, compared with 160 on Spanish.SE, so that's not a big difference. On the other hand, I expect Spanish.SE to grow faster in public beta, because there are far more English speakers than Spanish speakers gravitating to Stack Exchange. The risk in pushing an English-language site about Spanish is losing all the native audience and gravitating towards basic questions and a lack of expert answerers.

Answer (score 8):

I think we need to allow both.

I have two reasons for this:

1. Many beginners to the Spanish language won't be able to participate if they are required to read/write everything in Spanish.
2. Many beginners to the English language won't be able to partcipate if they are required to read/write everything in English.

I would like to encourage non-English speakers to use this site (and other SE sites), as I thik that will make this site stronger, as well as make the rest of SE stronger (especially as other bi/multi-lingual sites are being launched).

I also think we should, when possible, try to respect the language of the question.  That is to say, if the question is in English, answer in English, if it's in Spanish, answer in Spanish.  However, if you don't feel you speak the OP's language strongly enough to answer in their language, answering in your own language is better than not answering at all.  Someone else can always translate if appropriate.

If we do choose to accept Q&A in both languages, that does mean we may find duplicates. When this happens, I would encourage closing/merging them, and translating the relevant Q/A into both languages so that both OPs can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I think both should be allowed. I understand that people asking here are english-speaking people learning or want to learn spanish. So, if they ask in english, I suppose that they're not yet fluent (or daring!) enough to pose their question fully in spanish, and should be answered in english too; and if they ask in spanish, I suppose they're both asking and practicing their spanish, and should be answered in spanish so they can practice a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should accept both English and Spanish in titles and bodies of questions and answers.

But I also think that we should strongly encourage including English as well in Spanish posts to maximize the audience. I wish they did this in the other L & U sites. I participate in all of them but, especially in Japanese L & U I just don't have the ability to handle whole posts in Japanese and even Google Translate often can't handle them well.

If you wish to post in Spanish and have good English I encourage you to use both. If your English is not good enough I encourage others to edit posts to include English translations.

I do think titles are better in English. Especially as far as handling duplicate questions. If you ask a question in English that has previously been asked and answered in Spanish is it a duplicate? What if your Spanish is not at the level to read the prior question and answer?

I do think tags should be in English but it does no harm at all to have also have Spanish tag synonyms for them.

Answer (score 0):

I say we should keep the  Q/A in English, this will allow non-Spanish speakers to fully understand our questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the better is to ask and answer in Spanish. The best way to learn a language is to read, and write, and listen to it, and do that things over and over again.

Or, make your answer in the same language of the question.

And for tags I believe the same. Use Spanish. So the users are used to it.

Comment: I agree it's helpful to learn this way, but the site will probably gain better traction if questions and answers are in English.

Comment: So, jjeaton, you are saying that to gain public we have to do all in English? Is this site to learn or to attract users?

Comment: @unkiwii, both. We should reach a compromise

Comment: @unkiwii, I'm saying if we want the site to make it out of private beta, we have to have people using it (not that that's the sole purpose of the site, just that if no one uses it, it dies, and then no one gets to learn :) ). Many beginners who are trying to learn the language would be scared away of a site entirely in Spanish, even though I agree that it can be a better way to learn.

Comment: @JuanManuel, agreed. The site is for learning, and we need people here to make it a useful community for learning.

Comment: I think that we want pros and experts here. That kind of people that are fluent in Spanish and can answer all (or nearly all) of our questions maybe don't speak English. So I stand in my position, I think that in a site of Spanish L&U, Spanish must be used (the same for other languages)

Comment: @unkiwii, I agree we want experts here, however, this isn't the same tactic that 2 out of the other 3 SE language sites have taken. Even the french one showed a great example in Meta of a bi-lingual question.