# Should tags be in English, Spanish, or both?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shall we switch to Spanish-language tags?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/shall-we-switch-to-spanish-language-tags)

As it's not directly asked in [this question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-question-and-answer-bodies-in-spanish), should tags on this site be in English only, Spanish only, or both? If both, how should we determine how to correctly tag a question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They should be exclusively English except for the cases where there are no English equivalents.

If the [ceceo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceceo) tag existed, for example, it would have to be in Spanish.

[Wikipedia: ceceo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceceo)

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, they should be English only

Answer (score 4):

They should be in English when there is an English term.

They should be in Spanish when there is no English term but there is a Spanish term.

It does not hurt to have Spanish tag synonyms for English tags, in fact I think such tag synonyms should be strongly encouraged.