# Shall we switch to Spanish-language tags?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

We seem to have had a very positive reaction to the idea of making [Spanish our official site language](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/219/12), which pleases me.  This does, however, bring up another question, one we [previously addressed](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/12) when English was our "official" language:

### Should tags be in English, Spanish, or both?

And the decision from that post, as provided [@Richard's answer](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14/12):

> They should be exclusively English except for the cases where there are no English equivalents.
>
> If the [ceceo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceceo) tag existed, for example, it would have to be in Spanish.
>
> [Wikipedia: ceceo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceceo)

Do we want to stick to this policy of English-only tags, or switch to Spanish (except when there is no Spanish equivalents)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I propose changing our tagging policy, and making all tags in Spanish, except when there is no Spanish equivalent for a concept.

Furthermore, I suggest making the English versions of the tags synonyms with the Spanish versions.  This will reduce the need for a massive re-tagging effort of all current questions, and will also make it easier for non-fluent Spanish speakers to ask and search for questions.

Comment: Yes, it makes no sense to ask in Spanish and tag in English :P

Comment: I second this, quite smart.

Comment: This should be updated in the FAQ, then.

Comment: @jrdioko: thanks, I'm surprised I forgot to do that earlier.  The FAQ has now been updated.

Comment: Good one, well done!

Comment: @Flimzy Sorry, but I should disagree. There are many users here. Some of them are newbie in Spanish. The tags should be in both Spanish and English I think; so that the newbies don't become confused.

Comment: @aminabzz: I think you're about 8 years late to the party. But even so, having tags in both languages was never really on the table, except as aliases (which is already in place) and would be the most confusing of all possible options.