# The great SL&U tag/question cleanup of 2012

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

So we've decided to switch to [Spanish-language tags](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/226/12). Yay!

This means questions need to be re-tagged.  But first, we need new tag names!

## Don't start re-tagging questions yet!

Let me repeat that: Don't start re-tagging questions yet. It will be much easier, at least for the popular tags, for a moderator or high-rep users to create synonyms and do some tag merges.  So for the time being, please just sit tight on the edits. (Feel free to use either English or Spanish tags when asking new questions).

Some tag translations are obvious:

- food → *comida*

Some are less obvious:

- word-choice → ???

It's possible we may even decide some tags shouldn't exist.

Below is a list of our current English-language tags, and the number of questions on each, along with their new Spanish translation.  Any without a translation are fair game for an answer below to suggest a translation or other fate for the tag.  Once a decision is made on that tag, I (or someone) can update the below list to reflect that decision.

---

### Uncompleted

- [phrase](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) x 113 →
- [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) x 103 →
- [regional-differences](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional-differences) x 55 →
- [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions) x 45 → (synonyms: `definitions`, `meaning`)
- [term-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-choice) x 22 →
- [spelling](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) x 10 →
- [terminology](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) x 10 →
- [abbreviations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abbreviations) x 9 →
- [connotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotations) x 9 →
- [nuances](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuances) x 9 →
- [phonology](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology) x 8 →
- [resources](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) x 8 →
- [accents](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accents) x 7 →
- [expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) x 7 →
- [history](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) x 7 →
- [preterite](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preterite) x 7 →
- [standard-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standard-spanish) x 7 →
- [time](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) x 7 →
- [diacratics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diacratics) x 6 →
- [letters](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letters) x 6 →
- [lyrics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics) x 6 →
- [nouns](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) x 6 →
- [politeness](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness) x 6 →
- [language-comparison](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-comparison) x 5 →
- [verb-forms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-forms) x 5 →
- [deixis](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deixis) x 4 →
- [infinitive](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive) x 4 →
- [learning](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) x 4 →
- [morphology](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/morphology) x 4 →
- [aspect](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspect) x 3 →
- [imperfect](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperfect) x 3 →
- [indicative](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicative) x 3 →
- [conditional](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) x 3 →
- [distincion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distincion) x 3 →
- [interrogatives](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrogatives) x 3 →
- [irregular-forms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irregular-forms) x 3 →
- [linguistics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) x 3 →
- [loanwords](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loanwords) x 3 →
- [passive-voice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice) x 3 →
- [poetry](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) x 3 →
- [transportation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) x 3 →
- [alphabet](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphabet) x 2 →
- [archaisms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaisms) x 2 →
- [borges](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borges) x 2 →
- [conversation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation) x 2 →
- [compounds](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compounds) x 2 →
- [dialects](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects) x 2 →
- [education](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) x 2 →
- [future](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future) x 2 →
- [fixed-expressions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expressions) x 2 →
- [gender-neutrality](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-neutrality) x 2 →
- [grammatical-number](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-number) x 2 →
- [grammatical-person](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-person) x 2 →
- [imperative](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperative) x 2 →
- [internet-slang](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-slang) x 2 →
- [interrogative-words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrogative-words) x 2 →
- [latin](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) x 2 →
- [neutral-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutral-spanish) x 2 →
- [parts-of-speech](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parts-of-speech) x 2 →
- [past-participle](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-participle) x 2 →
- [personal-a](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-a) x 2 →
- [phone-conversation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phone-conversation) x 2 →
- [phonetics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics) x 2 →
- [popular-media](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popular-media) x 2 →
- [proper-nouns](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proper-nouns) x 2 →
- [semantic-range](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantic-range) x 2 →
- [senses](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senses) x 2 →
- [term-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-request) x 2 →
- [terms-of-address](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms-of-address) x 2 →
- [verb-moods](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-moods) x 2 →
- [word-order](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order) x 2 →
- [acronyms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acronyms) →
- [answers](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers) →
- [basque](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basque) →
- [calques](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calques) →
- [capitalization](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization) →
- [code-switching](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-switching) →
- [comma](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma) →
- [concepts](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concepts) →
- [controlled-language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controlled-language) →
- [dative](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dative) →
- [device-support](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-support) →
- [digraphs](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digraphs) →
- [figure-of-speech](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-of-speech) →
- [goodbyes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goodbyes) →
- [health](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) →
- [inflection](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inflection) →
- [informal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/informal) →
- [indrect-speech](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indrect-speech) →
- [interpretation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation) →
- [irony](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irony) →
- [jokes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jokes) →
- [kinship](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinship) →
- [language-academies](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-academies) →
- [language-change](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change) →
- [laughter](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laughter) →
- [letter-writing](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letter-writing) →
- [listener](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listener) →
- [metaphor](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphor) →
- [negative-words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-words) →
- [neologism](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neologism) →
- [neuter](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neuter) →
- [nominalization](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nominalization) →
- [online-resources](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources) →
- [people](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people) →
- [quotation-marks](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotation-marks) →
- [quotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotations) →
- [quote](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quote) →
- [redundancy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy) →
- [requests](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requests) →
- [response](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/response) →
- [rhetoric](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhetoric) →
- [rules](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) →
- [style](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) →
- [teach](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teach) →
- [valencia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valencia) →
- [vehicles](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicles) →
- [verb-inflection](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-inflection) →
- [writing](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) →

Comment: I havenn't tried it, but, what about tags that need tilde? For example, it should be [tag:números] instead of [tag:numeros]. How does SE behave in this cases?

Comment: I see the system does not allow diacritic accents in tags or links. Shows we ask in SO to encode them?

Comment: It would be much more useful to order the tags by how much they are used, rather than alphabetically. This way we can more easily focus on the most important tags first and see how far down the list we can get.

Comment: @hippietrail: Done.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions on hippietrail's suggested tags:

- [word-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) x 179 → [seleccion-lexica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seleccion-lexica) [lexico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lexico)
- [idiom](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom) x 45 → [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) ***Done***
- [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions) x 45 (synonyms `definitions`, `meanings`) → [significados-definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significados-definiciones) (synonyms `sentidos`, `significados` and `definiciones` are probably not needed thanks to the tag completion/suggestion feature of Stack Exchange.) [significados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significados) is a better traslation for "meanings".

Comment: Note that our English tagging system included [tag:regional-differences] as distinct from [tag:regionalisms]. The latter suggests mainly vocabulary or senses that exist only in certain places whereas the former includes all other ways in which a language can vary. To me `localismos` sounds like a synonym for `regionalismos` though.

Comment: Is *acepciones* another alternative to *sentidos* and *significados*? I was never totally clear on how to use the three properly.

Comment: *Acepción* is each *significado* of a word. So they are very related, but not exactly synonyms. *Acepción* is usually used bearing in mind that the word might have other meanings. So, if you say "significados" in plural, you can say "acepciones", but if you say "significado" in singular as the meaning of a word, "acepción" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @hippietrail my mistake, you are right.

Comment: Ah yes more like "senses" than "meanings" in English. I see now that "senses" doesn't make much sense as a tag. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

OK so since I don't believe I can make synonyms or do tag merges, here's some suggestions from me:

- [word-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) x 179 → [seleccion-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seleccion-de-palabras) ***Done***
- [phrase](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) x 113 → *This is not a good tag even in English! The best we could do in Spanish is maybe `expresión`.*
- [word-usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) x 103 → *This is not a good tag even in English! I suggest changing to [uso-de-terminos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-terminos) or [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras).*
- [regional-differences](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regional-differences) x 55 → [diferencias-regionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-regionales)
- [idiom](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom) x 45 → *This is not a good tag even in English! The difficulty of translating it to Spanish proves the point. [idiomatico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatico) is maybe closest but using a lone adjective seems wrong.*
- [meanings-definitions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meanings-definitions) x 45 (synonyms `definitions`, `meanings`) → [sentidos-definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentidos-definiciones) (synonyms `sentidos` and `definiciones` are probably not needed thanks to the tag completion/suggestion feature of Stack Exchange.)
- [orthography](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) x 31 → [ortografia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortografia) ***Done***
- [term-choice](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term-choice) x 22 → *See my recommendation for `word-usage` above.*
- [slang](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slang) x 17 → [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) ***Done***
- [syntax](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) x 14 → [sintaxis](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sintaxis) ***Done***

(I'll just suggest the number of terms that fit on the screen of my netbook per answer to avoid errors.)

Comment: I think idiom is a perfect tag for [idioms](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/idiom) and there is a direct translation to that in Spanish: [modismo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=modismo).

Comment: Idiom in English has several senses, some don't have a plural. Idioms in the plural has one obvious sense for the context of this site, but I'm not sure if our current singular tag is only used for that sense or not. *Modismo* isn't in my (poor) Spanish vocabulary though but I'll take your word for it that it's right (-:

Comment: Then, we should split "idiom" and "idioms". But it would require to check all the 45 tagged questions. About the uncountable meaning of idiom, I don't know what it is exactly in Spanish, even looking for the translation.

Comment: Well possibly split or possibly decide only one meaning is useful as a tag here. Looking at tagged questions is pretty important for good tag maintenance though, especially in a young beta site trying to make a name for itself. StackOverflow would not have such luxury these days (-:

Comment: Then, I let you guys decide about it, and I'll help to check the questions :) My opinion is that we should split.

Comment: I'm happy with whatever way is decided especially since I'm not so active here lately. But I would feel happy knowing that those deciding are aware of any gotchas when making their choices (-:

Answer (score 0):

(2nd screenload)

- [verb-tenses](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-tenses) x 13 → [tiempos-verbales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiempos-verbales) ***Done***
- [rare-words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rare-words) x 13 → [palabras-raras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palabras-raras) ***Done***
- [greeting](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greeting) x 13 → [saludos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saludos) ***Done***
- [gender](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) x 12 → [genero](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genero) ***Done***
- [punctuation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) x 11 → [puntuacion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puntuacion) ***Done***
- [mexico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexico) x 11 → *No need to change unless tags acquire the ability to include accented characters.*
- [spelling](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) x 11 → [deletrear](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletrear) or [como-deletrear](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/como-deletrear) or merge with [ortografia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortografia) above. *Note that merging would blur together the two different but overlapping English meanings.*
- [questions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions) x 10 → [preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preguntas) ***Done***
- [terminology](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) x 10 → [terminologia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminologia)
- [copulae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copulae) x 9 → [copulas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copulas) ***Done***
- [connotations](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotations) x 9 → [connotaciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotaciones)
- [formality](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formality) x 9 → [formalidad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formalidad) ***Done***

Comment: What are the two meanings of spelling?

Comment: @JoulSauron: There's not two meanings of spelling, there's two meanings of *ortografía*: **Orthography** and **spelling**. "Orthography, which can be loosely translated as "correct writing," encompasses spelling, word breaks (e.g. hyphenation), and other topics related to the written presentation of language." Currently we have both English tags but the most common translation of the noun sense of each of them is to the same Spanish word ***ortografía***.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. So to make it sure, is it that "orthography" is "gramática" and "spelling" is "ortografía"? Now I see why "orthography" has been always confusing for me :P

Comment: No "orthography" is "ortografía" and "spelling" is "ortografía" and "grammar" is "gramática". In English we have one word for which arrangement of letters is correct for writing a word and another to cover the broader field of writing correctly. Spanish only has one noun that covers both ... but the Spanish verb *deletrear* does only have the meaning of the English verb *to spell* without all the other stuff covered by *orthography*.

Comment: I see the problem now. As in Spanish, "deletrear" is not very important and in this site most of the cases would refer to *orthography*, I would simply merge spelling with [tag:ortografia].

Comment: @JoulSauron: It might be worth looking at [the questions tagged with "spelling"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) to make an informed decision though. Unlike in English, most Spanish words that might be spelled two ways would also have two pronunciations but it would seem strange to tag questions about *futbol* vs *fútbol* or *oscuro* vs *obscuro* as "pronunciation". And of course most Spanish speakers don't distinguish the sounds of *ll* and *y* or *c*, *s*, and *z* in certain positions; and not knowing when to omit or include *h*, since it is silent, is common too.

Comment: I think I favor *spelling* to *deletrear* and *orthography* to *orthografia*.