# Diacritic accents in links and tags

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, bug, estado-completado, estado-rechazado, enlaces

I've noticed that SE can't deal with links nor tags which has a character with diacritic accent in it.

About links, I feel it's important to allow this as RAE website needs the accent and depending on the format, it doesn't work:

- Writing `ú`: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

  It doesn't work at all.

  > URL: `buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número`
  >
  > [http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%C3%BAmero)
  >
  > [A link](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%C3%BAmero) (it doesn't work, though it's formatted like a link)
- Encoded in hexadecimal (`%FA`): [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

  It works, but the URL shows the hexadecimal.

  > URL: `buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%FAmero`
  >
  > http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%FAmero
  >
  > [A link](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%FAmero)
- Encoded in HTML (`&#250;` or `&uacute;`): [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

  It works fine, showing the `ú`.

  > URL: `buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n&#250;mero`
  >
  > http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número
  >
  > [A link](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número)

With tags it doesn't work at all:

- Writing `ú`: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

  > format: `[tag:números]`
  >
  > [números](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%bameros)
- Encoded in hexadecimal (`%FA`): [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

  > format: `[tag:n%FAmeros]`
  >
  > [tag:n%FAmeros]
- Encoded in HTML (`&#250;` or `&uacute;`): [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

  > format: `[tag:n&#250;meros]`
  >
  > [tag:números]

So, the best thing would be using HTML encoding when writing the URL. However, this would make users search the encoding of the desired character, and users might not know how to do this. Thus, my opinion is that we should ask SO to implement that an with URL an accent that is not encoded works:

The user writes:

> `buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número`

It shows:

> http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número

In tags, it depends on [how they are finally translated](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/the-great-slu-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012), but my opinion is that accents should work.

Do you feel this is important for the site, should make users to encode accents (or edit them), or should we ask to implement this feature (or fix the bug)?

Comment: You shouldn't often post "naked" URLs anyway. They're not user friendly. Better is something like [RAE dictionary for "número"](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%C3%BAmero).

Comment: @hippietrail I always try to format as you, but that's not my point ;) The thing is using a diacritic without encoding doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that part is a valid bug. I think you should file it as a bug report on meta.SO - it may even already be there.

Comment: Related MSO post/bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135142/165502

Comment: This is part of our ongoing work to better support unicode characters on our sites in general. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stripping issue in tags has been fixed for about a year.  The URL portion of this issue isn't going to be worked because the changes required to the markdown implementation and tag sanitizer are substantial, and users can use the hyperlink button in the editing toolbar to safely render such URLs.

For a more complete explanation, please refer to balpha's answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128824/136973

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure at what point this was fixed (for extended unicode characters in both urls and tags), but the example accented character links and tags all work/display fine as of 2019.

Comment: Good point. I see the accented one works (http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=número), while the hexa does not (http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=n%FAmero). I am tempted to add [meta-tag:status-completed] together with the already present [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: OK, I did it. See question and change if I missed anything. Thanks for noticing this old question!