# ¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Hace un tiempo hubo una gran iniciativa: [The great SL&U tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/231/1674). En ella se hizo una importante limpia de etiquetas redundantes o demasiado específicas, aprovechando la [decisión de usar etiquetas en castellano](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/1674).
Desde entonces hemos seguido creciendo como sitio ([más o menos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2490/1674)) y, como es normal en todo lugar donde pasa mucha gente, volvemos a tener cierto jaleo y desorden.

Pero antes de nada: ¿por qué es importante etiquetar las preguntas? El FAQ de Stack Exchange lo explica muy detalladamente en [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/209901), que puede resumirse en: etiquetamos para encontrar las cosas más rápidamente.

Así que como dijo la RAE, intentemos hacer un [*limpia, fija y da esplendor*](http://desequilibros.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/limpia-fija-y-da-esplendor-por-que-este.html#.V5nMVNx970o) hasta de aquí un par de años. ¿Qué os parece?

Mi idea es afrontar el proceso en dos partes para dos categorías:

## Etiquetas equivalentes

- primero, definamos qué etiquetas son equivalentes.
- una vez esto esté hecho, los moderadores podemos unir las que se decida. Esto es un momentito usando las herramientas de moderador y más rápido que [sugerir sinónimos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest). Interesante leer: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/209901)

## Etiquetas innecesarias

- definamos cuáles no aportan nada, para eliminarlas.
- esto no sé si se puede hacer como moderador (debo investigarlo), pero no debería tener mayor historia.

---

A continuación os detallo etiquetas que me parecen bastante equivalentes y para las que sería interesante valorar: ¿cuál es el deslinde entre ellas? ¿hay alguna superflua?

Añadid respuestas con vuestras sugerencias de agrupación para que entre todos decidamos cuál preferimos (mediante voto positivo si estamos de acuerdo y negativo si no lo estamos). No dudéis en incluir más etiquetas, cuya lista entera podéis encontrar en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags.

---

Bloque de frases idiomáticas, aquellas que tienen un significado diferente del literal:

- [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos)
- [frases-idiomaticas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frases-idiomaticas)
- [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion)
- [idiomatico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatico)
- [expresiones-fijas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones-fijas)

<sub>En [¿Es lo mismo un modismo que una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17650/1674) vimos que modismo, frase idiomática y expresión idiomática son lo mismo.</sub>

<sub>Posteriormente, en [¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674) resolvimos juntar todas menos [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n).</sub>

---

Bloque de determinar qué palabra debe usarse para describir un concepto determinado:

- [seleccion-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seleccion-de-palabras)
- [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras)
- [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones)
- [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado)
- [solicitud-de-termino](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-termino)
- [terminología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminolog%c3%ada)
- [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario)

---

Bloque de forma de tratamiento:

- [cortesía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortes%c3%ada)
- [formalidad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formalidad)

---

Bloque de dicción:

- [deletreo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletreo)
- [pronunciación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciaci%c3%b3n)
- [fonética](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fon%c3%a9tica)
- [categorías-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/categor%c3%adas-gramatical)

<sub>[fonética](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fon%c3%a9tica) es ahora sinónima de - [pronunciación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciaci%c3%b3n)</sub>

---

Bloque musical:

- [música](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m%c3%basica)
- [letras-de-canciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letras-de-canciones)

---

Bloque plurales:

- [número-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%bamero-gramatical)
- [persona-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona-gramatical)
- [plural](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plural)

---

<s>Bloque nombres:</s>

- [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios)
- [sustantivos-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos-propios)

<sub>Eliminado [sustantivos-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustantivos-propios) y creado sinónimo de [proper-nouns](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proper-nouns) para que apunte a [nombres-propios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios). Referencia: [¿Necesitamos la etiqueta “sustantivos-propios”? Hagámosla sinónima de “nombres-propios”](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2525/1674)</sub>

---

Bloque regiones:

- [diferencias-regionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-regionales)
- [dialectos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialectos)

---

<s>Regiones concretas con más de una etiqueta para la región, por ejemplo:</s>

- [chile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chile)
- [chilenismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chilenismo)

<sub>Completado tras [comentarlo con Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10344/palabras-del-mapuzungun-en-el-espa%C3%B1ol?noredirect=1#comment26995_10344). Ahora *chilenismo* es sinónimo de *chile*</sub>

---

Bloque puntuación / signos:

- [puntuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puntuaci%c3%b3n)
- [ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortograf%c3%ada)

---

Otras etiquetas:

- [adverbios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbios)
- [contracciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracciones)
- [connotaciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotaciones)

---

Bloque palabras de otros idiomas:

- [extranjerismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extranjerismo)
- [préstamo-lingüístico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pr%c3%a9stamo-ling%c3%bc%c3%adstico)

Si es adaptado, es préstamo lingüístico y no extranjerismo. Por ejemplo, *suéter* es préstamo y *business* es extranjerismo.

---

<s>Bloque habla coloquial:</s>

- [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga)
- [coloquialismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloquialismos)

<sub>En [¿Deberían “jerga” y “coloquialismos” ser etiquetas sinónimas?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2575/1674) se optó por hacer que [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) sea sinónima de [vocabulario-técnico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico).</sub>

Comment: Related post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag

Comment: Interesante: [How do you determine when a tag is bad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/1983854).

Answer (score 1):

Venga, voy a intentar responder:

- Bloque de frases idiomáticas, aquellas que tienen un significado diferente del literal: mi propuesta es quitar todas ellas y reducirlas a una, dado que creo que ya hiciste [una pregunta al respecto](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17650/12637) sobre si la RAE consideraba todas ellas iguales. Yo dejaría [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones).
- Bloque de determinar qué palabra debe usarse para describir un concepto determinado: aquí veo varios bloques independientes. Por un lado, [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras) y [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%c3%a9rmino) implican elegir una palabra que mejor represente un concepto. Por otro, [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones) y [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado) sirven para aclarar mejor el concepto que representa una palabra. Por último, [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras), [terminología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminolog%c3%ada) y [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario) implicarían explicar las diferencias entre dos o más términos aparentemente similares, siendo la última etiqueta un poco más genérica y que podría implicar a otro tipo de preguntas, como las de aclarar un término.
- Bloque de forma de tratamiento: dejaría [cortesía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cortes%c3%ada).
- Bloque de dicción: por un lado tendríamos [deletreo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletreo) y por otro uniría [pronunciación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciaci%c3%b3n) y [fonética](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fon%c3%a9tica).
- Bloque musical: dejaría [letras-de-canciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/letras-de-canciones). Preguntas como "qué instrumento musical es la 'batería'" no deberían estar en [música](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m%c3%basica), sino en [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) o [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario).
- Bloque plurales: las etiquetas [número-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n%c3%bamero-gramatical) y [persona-gramatical](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persona-gramatical) y [plural](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plural) deberían fusionarse con [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica).
- Bloque nombres: ya editado.
- Bloque regiones: las fusionaría en [diferencias-regionales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-regionales). Las preguntas sobre [dialectos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialectos) deberían en todo caso versar sobre las particularidades de formas del habla existentes en cualquier país hispanohablante, y que no puedan ser consideradas como un idioma aparte. Pero las preguntas sobre particularidades de algún dialecto siempre se pueden enmarcar dentro de otra categoría, según la pregunta. Reconozco que en esta etiqueta tengo dudas.
- Regiones concretas con más de una etiqueta para la región: dejaría solo las etiquetas con los nombres de los países. Así, [chilenismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chilenismo) se fusionaría con [chile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chile).
- Bloque puntuación / signos: Fusionarlos todos con [ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortograf%c3%ada).
- Otras etiquetas: dejaría etiquetas genéricas como [adjetivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjetivos), [verbos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbos), [adverbios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbios) y demás categorías que abarcan grandes cantidades de preguntas. La etiqueta [contracciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracciones) se fusionaría con [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica), y [connotaciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotaciones) podría fusionarse con [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras). La etiqueta [viajes-en-el-tiempo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/viajes-en-el-tiempo), creada a modo de broma para una única pregunta, se puede eliminar.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho la respuesta, Carlos. Como hay muchos elementos en discusión, creo que puede ser más fácil debatirlo desglosándolo en subpreguntas, al menos para los grandes bloques.

Comment: chile y chilenismo sí, perfecto. De hecho, hoy mismo se lo [consulté a Rodrigo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10344/palabras-del-mapuzungun-en-el-espa%C3%B1ol#comment26986_10344), pues fue quien creó la segunda.

Comment: @fedorqui sin problema, sabía que querías hacer subpreguntas, ya que es un tema amplio, pero en todo caso aquí quedan ya mis ideas generales. :-)

Comment: Empecemos con [¿Deberíamos usar una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag? modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674).

Comment: ¿Y si juntáramos [tag:definiciones] con [tag:significado]? Veo que se usan indistintamente y de hecho definiciones ya incluye [tag:meaning] ([sinónimos que tiene](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/definiciones/synonyms))

Comment: @fedorqui si se usan indistintamente... yo entendía que "definiciones" era más para descripciones formales (en diccionarios) de palabras o expresiones, y "significado" era más para cuando la palabra o expresión va en un contexto específico, o cuando se trata de dilucidar el significado de algo que no viene en el diccionario (tal vez algún neologismo o expresión coloquial). Pero si quieres plantearlo porque al final tener ambas puede generar confusión, ya sabes, pregunta específica en Meta y adelante.

Comment: Sí, la definición e idea de ambas etiquetas es distinta a nivel teórico, pero en el día a día no se está haciendo y ahora cada una tiene 300 entradas muy intercambiables.