# ¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

<sub>Esta es una subpregunta de [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) para poder debatir uno a uno cada uno de los bloques.</sub>

---

Las frases idiomáticas son aquellas que tienen un significado diferente del literal: *dar en el clavo*, *hacer la vista gorda*...

En [¿Es lo mismo un modismo que una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17650/1674) la RAE nos indicó que modismo, frase idiomática y expresión idiomática son lo mismo.

Actualmente tenemos un gran volumen de preguntas de este tipo. Es fantástico y muy enriquecedor, pero parece que hay cierta confusión a la hora de etiquetarlas. He identificado que tales preguntas suelen llevar alguna (o varias) de las siguientes etiquetas:

- [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos)
- [frases-idiomaticas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frases-idiomaticas)
- [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion)
- [idiomatico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatico)
- [expresiones-fijas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones-fijas)

En base a lo descrito arriba, parece que tal distinción no aporta demasiado. Por tanto, ¿creéis que deberíamos unirlas? Si es así, ¿bajo qué nombre? Yo optaría por usar *expresiones* o *frases idiomáticas*. Y muy importante también: ¿qué descripción debería tener (tanto el *excerpt* como la descripción general).

---

Idioms are those sentences that have a non-literal meaning: the union of the words makes a different meaning all together. *Dar en el clavo*, *hacer la vista gorda* are some examples.

In [¿Es lo mismo un modismo que una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17650/1674) RAE told us that *modismo*, *frase idiomática* and *expresión idiomática* are the same.

Currently, many of the questions in our site are related to this topic. This is great and giving a good background. However, there seem to be quite confusion on how to tag them. I have identified those questions using one (or many) of these tags:

- [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos)
- [frases-idiomaticas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frases-idiomaticas)
- [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion)
- [idiomatico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatico)
- [expresiones-fijas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones-fijas)

According to the beforementioned, such distinction seems to be useless and generate entropy instead of order. So, should we join these tags? If so, which one should be the canonic? I would go for *expresiones* or *frases idiomáticas*. Also important: what description should the tag have? This also includes the excerpt.

---

<sub>Nótese que todo lo relativo a crear sinónimos entre etiquetas lo podemos hacer los moderadores directamente, sin tener que editar pregunta a pregunta. A partir de ese momento, una pregunta etiquetada con una de ellas pasa silenciosamente a llevar la "canónica".

Podéis ver la lista entera de etiquetas en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags.</sub>

Comment: Ojo que [idiomático](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KuNIbg4) tiene dos acepciones. Una de ellas es sinónimo de modismo (=no deducible de los componentes por separado, corresponde al inglés _idiom_) y otra no es más que "propio del idioma" (aplicable, quizás, a que simplemente la gramática sea correcta, que los giros no sean forzados, y al inglés [_idiomatic_](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aidiom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b#safe=active&q=define:idiomatic) ). Deberíamos distinguir?

Comment: @Rafael a mi parecer, la segunda acepción de idiomático caería dentro de la gramática en cuanto a construcción de frases. Por tanto, sería la primera acepción de idiomático la que se incluiría en la etiqueta X que elijamos

Comment: Me preocupa que los angloparlantes eligen con cierta frecuencia "frases idiomáticas" para _idiomatic_ --> gramática natural/correcta. Por ejemplo, en [esta pregunta reciente](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18507/idiomatic-ways-of-saying-as-we-talked-about-like-i-said-etc)

Comment: @Rafael veo que es un mal común, si bien en este caso se sobre etiquetó: "modismos" y "idiomático". Probablemente venga de que al poner etiquetas y empezar con "idiom..." se sugiere "frase-idiomática". Debemos decidir ya sobre la fusión de etiquetas (cerrar el debate en los comentarios a las respuestas). Los otros casos que veas, no dudes en re-etiquetarlos. Añado: veo que la definición en [tag:idiomático](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/idiom%C3%A1tico/info) es mala: _Preguntas sobre frases con sentido propio, diferente al que pueden expresar sus distintos componentes por separado_.

Comment: @Rafael de hecho, veo que en [english.se] tienen [_idiomatic_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic) como sinónimo de _idioms_, mientras que en [french.se] crearon una interesante [_formulation-idomatique_](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulation-idiomatique). Me gusta esto último y podría ser la solución. ¿Te animas a abrir el debate en una pregunta aparte, para así tener la visión del resto de gente?

Comment: ¿Y qué hacemos con "frase hecha"?  ¿Debe ser sinónimo de "modismo" o debe ser algo aparte?

Comment: @aparente001 una frase hecha es un dicho, para la cual tenemos la etiqueta [tag:dichos]. He creado el sinónimo

Comment: @fedorqui - Creo que una frase hecha puede ser un fragmento, mientras un dicho sería una oración completa.  Ejemplo de *frase hecha*: "mar de dudas."

Comment: @aparente001 ¿qué referencias tienes?

Comment: @fedorqui - https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21544/9385, primer párrafo.

Comment: @aparente001 pues qué bueno que fuera una respuesta a mi pregunta :O Dicho lo cual, veo muchas posibles teorías. Elimino el sinónimo y lo apunto para intentar crear una jerarquía en Meta.

Comment: @fedorqui - thanks.  This is a very interesting but thorny issue and I find it all rather confusing but fascinating.

Comment: @aparente I just posted a new question here in Meta to try to shed some light and be able to group these tags in a two-level classification: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2926/1674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobre si deberíamos unirlas: sí. Creo que ello ayudaría a reducir la confusión sobre las etiquetas. Eso sí, toda unión debe tener en cuenta dos aspectos:

- Las etiquetas que queden tras la fusión deben tener una descripción muy útil, para que las futuras preguntas tengan claro qué etiqueta usar.
- La fusión debería hacerse con sinónimos, para evitar daños colaterales a los usuarios que puedan tener medallas en alguna de las etiquetas a fusionar. ¿Qué pasaría si se borrara una etiqueta que ha repartido medallas? ¿Se perderían dichas medallas?

Sobre el nombre: se debería dejar la etiqueta más utilizada o la que más medallas tenga otorgada. Si una etiqueta que ha repartido medallas se deja de usar, los usuarios no podrán tener opción a medallas más importantes (plata, oro) en esa misma etiqueta.

Comment: Sobre las medallas: [nadie](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) ha ganado ninguna en ninguna de estas. Tampoco creo que sea una cosa importante, fíjate que [las únicas medallas que se pueden perder son precisamente las relativas a las etiquetas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120050/209901), por lo que no conviene cogerles mucho cariño :) Muy buen punto el de la descripción, añado en la pregunta una petición para consensuar un texto.

Comment: @fedorqui en **expresión** estoy a medio camino (48/100) y en **modismos** voy más rezagado (20/100). Las otras ni me salen. La etiqueta más usada parece ser pues **expresión**, y si las otras pasan a ser sinónimos igual se suman las puntuaciones y tendría la medalla más cerca. :-D

Comment: Nótese que unas cuantas de tus respuestas allí tienen ambas etiquetas. Deberías sustraer unas de las otras. Por ejemplo, [`user:12637 is:a -[expresion] [modismos]`](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12637+is%3Aa+-%5Bexpresion%5D+%5Bmodismos%5D)

Comment: @fedorqui cierto, entre las dos etiquetas me salen 57 puntos si quitamos las duplicadas, y no 68. Pero sería un avance en todo caso. Y desde luego la gente tendría más fácil conseguir medallas en las etiquetas fusionadas, así podría tener más vida el sitio.

Comment: Como no hay más comentarios después de estos días, procedo a crear los sinónimos hacia [modismos]. Inicialmente no uno las etiquetas por si tenemos que tirarlo atrás. De momento, dejo [expresión] fuera, a ver si angus se pronuncia para zanjar el tema. Ya se pueden ver en http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all

Answer (score 0):

Sobre si hay que unirlas: sí, por supuesto, pero dejando afuera [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion), que creo que es mucho más abarcativo (habría que editar las preguntas con ese tag). Con respecto a qué etiqueta debería ser la canónica, yo propongo [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos), simplemente porque me molestan las etiquetas sin tildes.

Sobre el texto, el actual de [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion) está bastante bien, al menos para empezar. Tal vez agregarle los sinónimos:

> Los modismos también se llaman *expresiones fijas* o *idiomáticas*, o *frases hechas* o *idiomáticas*.

o algo así.

Comment: Uhms, la etiqueta [expresión] es problemática pues. Dejarla y tener [modismos] por otro lado podría inducir a error y que hubiera que ir limpiando periódicamente. Sería interesante distinguir qué tipos de expresiones tenemos y etiquetar con esa lista. Para mí, esto sería modismos, refranes y proverbios. No sé si me dejo alguno...

Comment: ¿Te molestan las etiquetas con o sin tildes?

Comment: Entiendo que quieras dejar fuera la etiqueta **expresión**, pero me gustaría aclarar qué diferencias ves entre las dos. Imagino que como dice @fedorqui en la pregunta, un modismo es una expresión en la que el conjunto de la frase expresa una cosa diferente a la suma de las partes, lo que hace que los modismos sean un subconjunto del total de expresiones. Por otro lado, el sinónimo que comentas ¿es para la etiqueta **expresión** o para **modismos**?

Comment: angus: para intentar cerrar el debate y optar por una solución, ¿podrías dar tu visión a lo que preguntaba @CarlosAlejo?

Comment: @Charlie - Creo que angus quería que **modismos** se sinonimizara con todo menos **expresión**, que proponía dejar aparte. // Yo en lo personal a estas alturas tengo en la mente un gran pantano de confusión.