# Diferencia entre "Tilde" vs. "Acentuación"

Tags: discusión, soporte, etiquetas

No entiendo la diferencia entre estas dos etiquetas:

[tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tilde)

y

[acentuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%c3%b3n)

Comment: Interesante recordar: [La RAE acepta la palabra _acento_ para denominar a la _tilde_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21844/1674)

Answer (score 7):

None at all.
In fact, we didn't even have a [tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tilde) tag until Mörkö created it 2 days ago while posting this question: [¿Qué forma es 'érase' y por qué lleva tilde?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/qu%C3%A9-forma-es-%C3%A9rase-y-por-qu%C3%A9-lleva-tilde)

I've edited said question to tag it as [acentuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%c3%b3n) instead, so now the [tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tilde) tag doesn't have any questions and it should get auto-deleted in a couple days, I think.

That doesn't mean it wouldn't be a good idea to have [tilde](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tilde) as a synonym for [acentuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%c3%b3n), though.

Comment: En las _reviews_ no avisa de _Tag Synonyms_ pendientes de ser aprobados. Acabo de proponer "tilde" como sinónimo de "acentuación" (porque aunque llevas razón en lo que dices, esto volverá a pasar, y mejor dejar el sinónimo que andar reetiquetando y esperando a que se borre el tag).  Estaba pendiente tb de aprobación "dichos" como sinónimo de "expresiones". Parece ser que "dichos" no es lo mismo que "refranes" o "modismos"? Lo investigaré un poco y hago algo con esta sugerencia de sinónimo.

Comment: Gracias a todos, me gusta la idea de hacer "tilde" synónimo de "acentuación." // ¿Por qué no discutimos "fixed expressions" en otro hilo aparte?

Comment: @Diego y walen. Tal y como comenté en el chat hace un par de días, creo que podemos retomar [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) y [¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674) y terminar la limpia que tenemos pendiente.

Comment: For English speakers tilde means the diacritic which distinguishes n from ñ so having something else as the main tag may indeed be preferable.