# ¿Cómo podríamos clasificar las etiquetas por tipos de sentencias?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Después de [¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674), [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) tiene estos sinónimos:

- frases idiomáticas
- expresión idiomática
- idiomático
- expresiones fijas
- ¿y [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n)? pendiente

Después tenemos algunas pocas preguntas con [aforismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aforismo), [refranes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refranes) y [proverbios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proverbios), que según [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "refrán" y "proverbio"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17128/1674) serían conceptos diferentes y que Fundéu explica como *la única diferencia es que el aforismo y el proverbio son cortos y el refrán no tiene por qué serlo*. Esto se reafirma en [¿Qué diferencia hay entre locución, frase hecha, refrán y proverbio?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21540/1674), donde dicho y refrán se ve como muy parecidos.

Siguiendo lo [descrito por Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21544/1674), podríamos pues aventurar una jerarquía de este tipo:

Frases  (grupos de palabras):

- locución - funciona como la palabra que lo califica
- modismo, frase idiomática, expresión fija
- frase hecha

Oraciones (con sujeto y predicado):

- aforismo
- dicho
- proverbio
- refrán
- sentencia

Sugiero ir debatiendo al respecto en las respuestas e ir incorporando las "decisiones" en el texto de la pregunta. La idea a la larga es que toda pregunta de un tipo determinado use etiquetas de dos niveles: la del grupo que engloba y la particular.

- ¿Qué etiqueta genérica podría tener cada bloque?
- ¿Qué posibles sinónimos podrían crearse?

---

Equivalencias en inglés:

- proverbio - *proverb*
- refrán - ¿*saying, aphorism, adage, refrain*? Véase [English equivalent of *refrán*, which is less formal than a proverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/444372/37429)
- modismo - *idiom*
- Ojo: [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) tiene [fixed-expressions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expressions) (con *s*) como sinónimo, pero [fixed-expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expression) (sin *s*) es en cambio sinónimo de [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) (véase arriba, cómo [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) está pendiente de marcar como sinónimo de [modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismo)).

Comment: Un pensamiento preliminar (y otro día leo todo el post con más cuidado): para mí, *idiomático* debe ser aparte, o no existir.  Voy a explicar lo que yo entiendo con este adjetivo.  Mucha gente maneja el inglés porque ha llegado a ocupar un papel de herramienta de comunicación internacional.  Pero sucede a veces en ELU que alguien pregunta algo acerca del uso de una palabra o una expresión, y la única explicación que se le puede dar es "the phrase as you wrote it is not idiomatic."  Es decir, no es *natural*.  (Esto sucede aquí también a veces, but no tan seguido como en ELU.)

Comment: @aparente001 entiendo, si bien es importante usar referencias para sustentar estas opiniones. En este caso, [la RAE nos indicó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17685/1674) que _Como expresión fija cuyo significado no se deduce de las palabras que la forman se usan MODISMO y EXPRESIÓN IDIOMÁTICA_. En cuanto a _idiomático_ a secas, sí, estoy de acuerdo en que es algo de otro tipo y que no solo aplicaría a preguntas sobre frases, locuciones, refranes, etc, sino a una forma de escribir cosas tal y como un nativo lo haría.

Comment: En castellano idiomático no tiene ese significado de "natural" que sí tiene en inglés. Aún así la definición de una expresión propia del idioma o de frase hecha si la comparten.

Comment: @blonfu ostras, [tienes razón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KuNIbg4). De tanto verlo acabé asumiéndolo. Estamos bien, pues, con [tag:idiomático] apuntando a [tag:modismos].

Comment: ¿Falso cognado, entonces?  Interesante.  Yo no sabía eso.  ¡Material para una pregunta!

Comment: @blonfu - Eché un ojo al DLE y encontré "1. adj. Propio y peculiar de una lengua determinada."  Eso concuerda con la acepción a la que me refería.  Entonces no entiendo bien tu comentario.  ¿Puedes explicar un poco más, por favor?

Comment: @aparente001 No es lo mismo, es cierto que algo que es propio de un idioma generalmente sonará natural a sus hablantes nativos pero algo que suene natural no tiene por que ser propio o peculiar del idioma

Comment: @blonfu - No entiendo del todo, pero creo que el formato del comentario no es apto para buena comprensión.  Redacté una pregunta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26100/9385

Comment: @fedorqui - No entiendo "sentencia".  Es lo mismo que "oracion"?  Oracion completa?