# Tag Housekeeping Requests

Tags: discusión, soporte, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, housekeeping

This is a page where simple tag housekeeping can be requested. If you have an idea for, for example, a tag synonym, this is a good place to record it.

If your simple request turns out to need more discussion than you thought it would (e.g. more than a couple of little comments), then that item should be moved to a separate Meta question of its own.

After some opportunity for discussion and voting on the proposals, moderators will proceed as follows:

- If consensus has been reached, moderators will carry out any necessary changes and add the tag [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).
- otherwise, the tag [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) will be added.

To keep the post clean, answers marked will be deleted after some time (users with enough reputation still can see those answers, so there is no doubt they are still reachable in case of need.)

**Help the moderators notice a new post by *flagging it* to have moderators check it!**

Note: **please avoid making new requests in comments**. Each request should be posted as a new answer to allow users to properly notice, discuss and vote the proposal.

Comment: In general: I'd like to see us gradually working on making sure each tag has an English synonym that will be easy for a Spanish learner to understand.

Comment: DONE @fedorqui - could you please make "geography" and "geografia" (without the accent) synonymous with "geografía"?

Comment: DONE @fedorqui - [tag:topónimo] needs toponimo and place-names.

Comment: @fedorqui - Hi there.  Another tiny request.  I think "nombre-colectivo" would be better than "nombres-colectivos".  Because the point of the whole thing is that it looks singular, but it works for a plural concept (I hope I got that right).

Comment: DONE And one more easy one: could you make "united-states" point to "estados-unidos" please?

Comment: @fedorqui - Question.  When I list all the tags, "lo" shows up -- that's okay -- but it shows up with its obsolete definition.  But when I click on it, I get the new version, with its new definition.  (Old definition: *Preguntas sobre el uso del pronombre "lo".*)  Is that some kind of programming bug?

Comment: DONE @fedorqui - Could you create "lenguaje-técnico" as a synonym of "vocabulario-técnico"?

Comment: DONE @fedorqui - I remember you said our pattern is to use plurals in tag names.  Would it make sense for [tag:expresion] to be plural?

Comment: DONE @fedorqui - we had two similar tags, [tag:construccion-y-obra] and the same but with the accent.  Would you mind removing the one without the accent, please?

Answer (score 1):

Creation of the tag español rioplatense, for the español rioplatense dialect , which includes regions of Argentina and Uruguay. The tag Argentina or Uruguay alone wouldnt be correct if the word is from the español rioplatense dialect, or both of the tags should always be included.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tag, [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras), which seems equivalent to [meaning-in-context](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context).  Could these be made synonyms?  (With *uso-de-palabras* as the primary tag.)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Movida la primera parte a [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas de Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/1674)</sub>

Creo que etiquetas como [housekeeping](/questions/tagged/housekeeping), [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) o [reference](/questions/tagged/reference) no son representativas, sino algo así como meta etiquetas que bien podrían eliminarse.

Comment: Bien hecho.  Propongo *formateo* (o *formateado* si prefieres); *tagging -> etiquetado, etiquette -> buen-trato, on-topic-off-topic -> validez-de-tópico* o *validez-de-tema*.  Nota que "on-topic-off-topic" viene de ELU Meta.  Me gusta ese enfoque.  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-off-topic  // Confieso que no entiendo bien la diferencia entre el etiquetado y el reetiquetado. // Propongo asimismo que se ponga esta respuesta en Featured.

Comment: @aparente001 tal vez debería publicar una pregunta separada del tipo [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/83) de Meta SOes. ¿Borro esta respuesta y lo muevo allí? Así hacemos lluvia de ideas

Comment: Me parece bien.

Comment: @aparente001 ya lo moví

Comment: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/9385

Answer (score 0):

En La Tertulia, un participante [propuso](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45358602#45358602):

> Que los tags [extranjerismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extranjerismos) y [palabras-extranjeras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palabras-extranjeras) sean sinónimos.

Otro [opinó](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45358889#45358889):

> Según lo que explica la RAE en [Tratamiento de los extranjerismos](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/que-contiene/tratamiento-de-los-extranjerismos), yo entendería palabras-extranjeras como el subconjunto extranjerismos crudos.

Ahorita hay tres preguntas etiquetadas con [palabras-extranjeras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palabras-extranjeras).

Comment: @walen - Me inclino a votar a favor de la respuesta.  A ver si fedorqui me convence que son distintas.

Comment: Yo opino que [tag:palabras-extranjeras] es un subconjunto de [tag:extranjerismos], tal y como indiqué. Es un subconjunto pequeño, pero no veo coherente apostar por los subconjuntos en unos casos y no hacerlo en otros. Sea como fuere, al haber tan pocas preguntas podría juntarse y luego separarse más adelante si crece en cantidad.

Comment: @fedorqui - Creo que un factor importante es típicamente el tamaño del subconjunto.  Ha pasado año y medio y el subconjunto sigue pequeñito, así que no veo inconveniente en combinar.  Por el otro lado, hay cierta ventaja con combinar -- usando etiquetas, es más fácil encontrar preguntas relacionadas.

Comment: sí, el tiempo da la razón. El sinónimo está propuesto desde hace un año, solo necesita un voto más: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/extranjerismos/synonyms

Comment: @fedorqui - Desgraciadamente, yo no puedo votar.  Me parece que es un defecto inherente del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

We have [formal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal) but not the opposite.  I propose we have one tag for the whole issue of formal mode of address vs. informal.  So, I'm suggesting all of the following be synonyms of each other:
tutear
usted
mode-of-address
formal
informal

Comment: Existe [tag:formal] y [tag:formalidad]. La primera la eliminaría.

Comment: @fedorqui - We have [tag:ser-estar].  How about [tu-Usted]?

Comment: suena bien, @aparente001.

Comment: @fedorqui - Here's another idea, taken from https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13497/uso-de-%c3%a1ndale-y-%c3%a1ndele#comment44709_26778: *tuteo-ustedeo*.  I had never heard "ustedeo" before!

Comment: Me neither! It sounds like a good tag to have.

Comment: @fedorqui - Would you like to query those who participate in La Tertulia to see which version they like better to be the main tag that everything points to?

Comment: feel free to do so

Answer (score 0):

We have a bit of a mess with foreign words.  There's *extranjerismos* -- very nice.  But we need to define a synonym that incorporates "foreign" -- maybe *foreign-words*.  I think I need help from the moderators for this.

Also, there is another tag that appears to be redundant, *palabras-extranjeras*. My guess is, this should be made a synonym of *extranjerismos*.

Comment: About the first point: not sure why we moderators are needed here, apart from to create the synonym. It is a decision by the community what taxonomy we want, we moderators do not have a superior knowledge to decide which is the _good_ one : )

Comment: About the second point: dupe of [another answer here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2979/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui - Mod help with the synonym creation would be much appreciated. // Thanks for the reminder -- believe it or not, this situation does not do justice to the extent of my memory problems.  They are just a fact of life that I am trying to resign myself to.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: In fact I didn't remember neither, it is just that I searched if this had been discussed before and found... an answer here :) So you are not alone!

Answer (score 0):

Do we have a tag for questions about the second person plural, and how in some areas this is expressed with *ustedes* and in some, *vosotros*?  If not, we need one!  But I don't know what to call it.  It's a major difference between Old World and New World Spanish, so it's important.

We already have a tag for *ustedeo*, but it means something else:

> Preguntas sobre el uso del pronombre "usted" como segunda persona del singular / Questions about the usage of the pronoun 'usted' to refer to the second person of the singular

(By the way, I'm going to try to modify that definition, to insert the concept of *formality*.)

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a tag for the concept of the omitted subject.  This is a special grammatical concept of Spanish that is interesting and important for Spanish learners, and therefore we have plenty of questions about this.  Example: [usted and its usage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1427/9385)

I'm not sure what to call it.

Comment: ¿[Sujeto elíptico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujeto_el%C3%ADptico)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not urgent but I'm writing it now so I won't forget.  Could we please have a tag for *datives* that would point to *objetos-indirectos*?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a tag for paradoxical gender (e.g. *la mano*) and maybe a separate one for feminine nouns that start with a vowel and therefore use the masculine article in the singular, e.g. *agua, asa*.  I'm not sure what to call them.  The first could be *género-paradójico* but I have no idea what to suggest for the other.

Answer (score -1):

Question: why are [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) and [modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismo) not synonymous?  When I look at the definitions, they seem to be interchangeable.  Is it just me who can't find much of a difference between the two?

Comment: Please, check for previous discussions before adding requests. For example [¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674) y [¿Cómo podríamos clasificar las etiquetas por tipos de sentencias?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2926/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui - My awful memory again.  Thanks for the links, I will read them.

Comment: In the first link you sent me to, if I understood right, the separation of *expresión* and *modismo* was intended to be temporary.

Comment: aparente: it is not clear how to work with these tags. Since they are not 'little tiny debates' to handle in an answer to this question, let's use [¿Cómo podríamos clasificar las etiquetas por tipos de sentencias?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2926/1674) to talk about these.

Comment: @fedorqui - Okay -- unless you'd be willing to have the conversation at https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674 instead? // Also please note I didn't actually write a proposal here for this, I simply asked a question.  In other words, if they're different, I was saying, could someone explain to me how to differentiate.

Comment: I think it is better to start the debate in the newly created question, since the other one already lost its momentum

Comment: _I simply asked a question_. Well, we intented to have this question as little easy requests, and it is working great so far (I am happy for this!). However, opening debates should go in different questions if we want more people to give their voice.

Comment: @fedorqui - I thought it would have a simple answer when I wrote it. // It's frustrating to have one issue discussed in two separate threads. // Okay, I will try.  I do find it confusing to go back and forth between two separate debates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79383/discussion-between-aparente001-and-fedorqui).

Comment: We have a severe lack of participation in Meta. If we do not put some order in how we do things, it becomes worse. Extended debates in comments, revisiting old posts and so on do not work well. That's why we either ask for basic things in here or create new debates (that is, questions) when things become less trivial.