# Is the "deletreo" tag needed?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, housekeeping

*Prologue: This question originally appeared at [Tag Housekeeping Requests](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/tag-housekeeping-requests). 
 I brought it over here and gave it a separate thread of its own because that request/proposal turned out to need more discussion than I thought it would.*

*Deletreo* means which letters appear in a word (and in what order), and *ortografía* covers that too, but also the use of symbols such as the accent mark, the diaerisis, and punctuation marks.

Right now we have [ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortograf%c3%ada) and [spelling](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) as synonyms, which I think is as it should be.  Their definition is

> Deletreo, puntuación, uso de tildes, etc. Correct spelling, punctuation, use of accent/diacritical marks, etc.

But we also have [deletreo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletreo), which is defined as

> Questions about the correct way of spelling a word. Preguntas sobre la forma correcta de escribir una palabra.

Here are two examples of questions tagged *deletreo*:

[¿Cómo escribo el subjuntivo presente de 'adelgazar'?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2618/9385)

[Is it "élite" or "elite"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19384/9385)

One is also tagged with *ortografía*; one isn't.  Is anything gained by tagging with just *ortografía*?

*This is intended to be a polling question, with a structure for fruitful discussion.*

Comment: It is worth noting what the DRAE says about [deletreo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C6bvTMf): _Decir separadamente las letras de cada sílaba, las sílabas de cada palabra y luego la palabra entera; Decir el nombre de cada una de las letras que constituyen una palabra." So that technically is "spelling a word _aloud_", quite different from [ortografía](_Conjunto de normas que regulan la escritura de una lengua; Forma correcta de escribir respetando las normas_)

Comment: This question is not as useful as it could be. OK, so we are polling, but **what will be the outcome of this poll?** If we don't need both tags, do we delete "deletreo" (Can we _explicitly_ say so if it is the intended outcome)? If we need both, do we make "deletreo" a synonym of ortografía/spelling? Or do we need "deletreo" but with its own meaning? Personaly, I think we don't need "deletreo" and the tag should be deleted, but others might disagree. In any case, I don't think that our call to action after polling is completely clear.

Comment: @Diego - The action step seemed obvious to me but if you think it was too much of a leap, please feel free to edit the question.

Comment: @diego - Your reasoning and your position are a helpful addition to the discussion.  If there is an answer in the poll that you can support, I hope you'll post a comment below it.  // Please feel free to add one or more additional answers to the poll.

Comment: @aparente001 It may be obvious in the case that we don't need the tag, but unclear if we decide to keep it (keep it as a synonym or as a tag with its own separated purpose?) Or if I vote that we don't need both tags does it mean the tag  should "disappear" by becoming a synonym (as opposed to be deleted)? To me if the tag is needed or not, and the call to action may be two separate things. It can't hurt to clarify the outcome of each choice in the poll. I'm not going to add additional options to the poll. I may add a comment, which will be lost under the 10 already existing for that choice.

Comment: @Diego good points! I would say: If _No_ wins, then we assume [tag:deletreo] is a subset of [tag:ortografía], so we merge those and create a synonym.

Comment: Fedorqui I was assuming that if _No_ wins the tag was not needed. @Aparente001 said that the action steps were obvious, but no clarification has been given in spite of my requests. I was just invited to edit the question. Maybe it doesn't matter and I'm overthinking it. In any case, since comments are used to request clarification (and since the answer was edited and further comments were added after I asked) it could not hurt to clarify that _obvious_ action step. Just saying "it seemed obvious to me but if it is not for you, you edit the question" doesn't help me to understand any better.

Comment: @Diego - I apologize if I seemed to be *expecting* you to edit the question -- that wasn't my intention, and I'm sorry.  I don't want you to feel pressured to edit it.  But you can if you want to. // You wrote, "Personally, I think we don't need "deletreo" and the tag should be deleted."  I'm inclined to agree, but I'm interested in the discussion, and the process.  If we keep the tag, I think it would be helpful to delineate more clearly when it should and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @walen quite simple: we use the tags we need at the time we are checking those. So far, I hadn't found any question that needed the [tag:deletreo], thus I didn't find the need to have it. Once you added the question [¿Cómo se deletrean las “palabras” con varias letras iguales seguidas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26643/1674) things change. It is the same reasoning why we don't have `[filipino-en-guinea-ecuatorial]` or `[preposición-de-con-subjuntivo]`: because currently they don't make any difference in classifying questions. Taxonomy keeps changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is helpful for certain questions to be tagged with [deletreo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletreo).

Comment: @walen thanks, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @walen in any case, most of the questions tagged with _deletreo_ don't seem to be using it in the way you support it to be. So if this option 'wins' it is necessary to do some retagging and fixing its scope, as well as writing a good excerpt.

Comment: @walen so it seems that we are discussing about the use of a tag that is not well defined. _Empezar la casa por el tejado_, básicamente. So let's agree on a definition of a tag and then see which ones deserve it.

Comment: @walen also, since you mention [tag:acentuación] is used for different situations. I don't think we should do that. Every tag should be used for one single concept. Otherwise it does not help classifying and finding similar questions.

Comment: Actually, one cannot hear anyone who is deletreando (spelling out) a word on this site. ***There are no sound files***. So, I d,v. here but not by clicking on the button.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no need to have both the [ortografía](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortograf%c3%ada) and [deletreo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletreo) tags.

Comment: If both tags exist, it's tempting to tag most spelling questions with both, so actually, one tag would be enough.  Since "ortografía" is the commonly used term in Spanish for talking about the concept of *spelling*, "ortografía" would be a more practical term to hold on to than "deletreo."

Comment: @walen - Sorry, I wasn't clear.  When I said *ortografía* is the commonly used term for talking about the concept of "spelling," I didn't mean that it is the commonly used term for talking ONLY about the concept of spelling.  I meant that when a native Spanish speaker has in mind what English speakers use the word "spelling" to express, they use the word "ortografía," not "deletreo."  For example, there are books for fourth graders entitled "Spelling," and "Ortografía."  There aren't any books entitled "Deletreo."  I have acknowledged ...

Comment: ... that they aren't one to one, that "ortografía" covers a much larger set.  In meaning.  But the places where the circles don't intersect in a Venn diagram can be clarified when we write the tag guidance.

Comment: @walen - Thanks for laying out your reasoning.  I will try to answer the question "What's the point?".  Look at the two example questions and their tag structure.  What do you think about the tags chosen in those two questions?  Do you think one needed [tag:deletreo] and the other didn't?  Do you think the one that has both tags gains anything by having [tag:deletreo], or would [tag:ortografía] be enough?  You might feel differently about those decisions than I do.  Maybe you'll be able to propose a flow chart for tagging those questions, with a clear logic.  I haven't been able to come...

Comment: ... up with one -- but that doesn't necessarily mean it's not possible.

Comment: spelling is ortografía, no doubt about it. Deletrear is to spell (out) a word. It is usually used when speaking. On a test or in a text: you have: errores de ortografía. But for this site, deletrear is not needed, as it is all **written**. There is no way anyone can "deletrear" something, and anyone can ***hear*** it being spelled out. The benefit is obvious. You should not have a tag you can't use.