# ¿Hay alguna manera en la que podamos hacer encuestas en el SE?

Tags: soporte, ámbito

Estaba pensando en una encuesta para el grupo, tal vez polémica, pero que siempre me ha interesado averiguar:

Cuales crees que son los dialectos mas bellos y mas feos del español.

Comment: Por cierto, hay casos en que los propios empleados de SE han hecho encuestas mediante typeform: [Where do we go from here? Take the survey!](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1324/21060) en [sound.se].

Answer (score 3):

El sistema de preguntas / respuestas bajo el que operamos se basa en que las preguntas contesten a lo que se pregunta.

Muy ocasionalmente se utiliza Meta en modo encuesta para decisiones sobre el uso (por ejemplo en [Is the "deletreo" tag needed?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2969/1674)), si bien tiende a descaconsejarse o considerarse el último recurso antes de agotar otras vías más abiertas que permitan ofrecer más matices.

Existe alguna petición de que haya entornos de encuestas: [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/209901). Pero de momento no existen.

En tu caso concreto, al ser un tema personal y subjetivo, lo más indicado sería que hicieras la encuesta en la sala de chat [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia). También puedes crear una pequeña encuesta con Google Forms o similares y enlazarla en el chat para que quien quiera participe.

Total, ganará el dialecto colombiano... :)

Comment: Muy buena fuente!, al parecer la petición no ha tenido muchas vistas o relevancia para otros stacks, pero creo que un stack del lenguaje que no es una ciencia exacta si no una construcción basada en usos y opiniones una encuesta si ayudaría a darnos una noción de lo que sucede, sobre todo si consideramos a los miembros del stack como una muestra de resultados !