# Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas de Meta

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, etiquetas, meta, renombrar-etiquetas

<sub>(publicado inicialmente en [Tag Housekeeping Requests](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2962/1674) pero movido a pregunta propia para mayor claridad) y basado en [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/83) de Meta SO.es.</sub>

Dado que en Spanish.SE ya usamos las etiquetas en castellano desde hace años y en Meta es un proceso en constante evolución pero sin que se finalice, ¿podrían añadirse las siguientes etiquetas en castellano y hacer que las ya existentes en inglés apunten a ellas?

- [election](/questions/tagged/election) → [elecciones](/questions/tagged/elecciones)
- [featured-items](/questions/tagged/featured-items) → [elementos-destacados](/questions/tagged/elementos-destacados)
- [design](/questions/tagged/design) → [diseño](/questions/tagged/dise%c3%b1o)
- [vote-to-reopen](/questions/tagged/vote-to-reopen) → [voto-de-reapertura](/questions/tagged/voto-de-reapertura)
- [review](/questions/tagged/review) → [colas-de-revisión](/questions/tagged/colas-de-revisi%c3%b3n)
- [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) y [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) → ¿[alcance](/questions/tagged/alcance)¿ ¿[ámbito](/questions/tagged/%c3%a1mbito)?

Luego hay que tener en cuenta que todo sitio Meta tiene un listado de etiquetas predeterminadass, tal y como se comenta en [Add a selection of default tags to all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62655/209901). Dada esa lista, se podría traducir de la siguiente manera:

- [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) -> [reputación](/questions/tagged/reputaci%c3%b3n)
- [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) -> [preguntas](/questions/tagged/preguntas)
- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) -> [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas)
- [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) -> [comentarios](/questions/tagged/comentarios)
- [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) -> [medallas](/questions/tagged/medallas)
- [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) -> [respuestas](/questions/tagged/respuestas)
- [search](/questions/tagged/search) -> [búsqueda](/questions/tagged/b%c3%basqueda)
- [voting](/questions/tagged/voting) -> [votos](/questions/tagged/votos)
- [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) -> [ediciones](/questions/tagged/ediciones)
- [bounty](/questions/tagged/bounty) -> [recompensas](/questions/tagged/recompensas)
- [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) -> [interfaz-de-usuario](/questions/tagged/interfaz-de-usuario)
- [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) -> [pregunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pregunta-espec%c3%adfica)
- [accepted-answer](/questions/tagged/accepted-answer) -> [respuesta-aceptada](/questions/tagged/respuesta-aceptada)
- [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) -> [formato](/questions/tagged/formato)
- [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) =
- [community-wiki](/questions/tagged/community-wiki) -> [wiki-de-comunidad](/questions/tagged/wiki-de-comunidad)
- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) -> [votos-negativos](/questions/tagged/votos-negativos)
- [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) =
- [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) -> [migración](/questions/tagged/migraci%c3%b3n)
- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) -> [votos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/votos-de-cierre)
- [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) -> [duplicados-exactos](/questions/tagged/duplicados-exactos)
- [etiquette](/questions/tagged/etiquette) -> [convenciones-sociales](/questions/tagged/convenciones-sociales)
- [notifications](/questions/tagged/notifications) -> [notificaciones](/questions/tagged/notificaciones)
- [users](/questions/tagged/users) -> [usuarios](/questions/tagged/usuarios)
- [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) -> [preguntas-cerradas](/questions/tagged/preguntas-cerradas)
- [hyperlinks](/questions/tagged/hyperlinks) -> [enlaces](/questions/tagged/enlaces)
- [data-dump](/questions/tagged/data-dump) =
- [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) -> [formulado-de-preguntas](/questions/tagged/formulado-de-preguntas)
- [delete](/questions/tagged/delete) -> [eliminación](/questions/tagged/eliminaci%c3%b3n)
- [recent-activity](/questions/tagged/recent-activity) -> [actividad-reciente](/questions/tagged/actividad-reciente)
- [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) -> [nuevos-usuarios](/questions/tagged/nuevos-usuarios)
- [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) -> [págna-de-perfil](/questions/tagged/p%c3%a1gna-de-perfil)
- [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) -> [reportes](/questions/tagged/reportes)
- [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) =
- [unanswered-questions](/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions) -> [preguntas-sin-respuesta](/questions/tagged/preguntas-sin-respuesta)
- [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) -> [reetiquetado](/questions/tagged/reetiquetado)
- [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) -> [moderación](/questions/tagged/moderaci%c3%b3n)
- [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) =
- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) -> [motivos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/motivos-de-cierre)
- [user-accounts](/questions/tagged/user-accounts) -> [cuentas-de-usuario](/questions/tagged/cuentas-de-usuario)
- [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) -> [formato](/questions/tagged/formato)
- [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) -> [etiquetas-favoritas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas-favoritas)
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) -> [votos-positivos](/questions/tagged/votos-positivos)
- [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) =
- [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) -> [estadísticas](/questions/tagged/estad%c3%adsticas)
- [login](/questions/tagged/login) =
- [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) =
- [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) -> [favoritos](/questions/tagged/favoritos)
- [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) -> [preguntas-eliminadas](/questions/tagged/preguntas-eliminadas)
- [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) -> [etiquetas](/questions/tagged/etiquetas)
- [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) -> [votos](/questions/tagged/votos)
- [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) -> [sinónimos-de-etiqueta](/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos-de-etiqueta)

Comment: Voy a ir revisando mi agenda para ver cuándo tengo un fin de semana entero libre para renombrar tanta etiqueta. :-D

Comment: Bien hecho. Propongo *formateo* (o *formateado* si prefieres); *tagging -> etiquetado, etiquette -> buen-trato, on-topic-off-topic -> validez-de-tópico* o *validez-de-tema*. Nota que "on-topic-off-topic" viene de ELU Meta. Me gusta ese enfoque. english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/… // Confieso que no entiendo bien la diferencia entre el etiquetado y el reetiquetado. // Propongo asimismo que se ponga esta respuesta en Featured.

Comment: "featured items" -- propusiste "elementos-destacados".  "Elementos" is bonito, pero tal vez no se necesita un termino tan creador en realidad.  "Preguntas" creo que tambien funcionaria.  (Pero no tengo objecion a *elementos*.)

Comment: Entiendo que esto solo lo pueden hacer los moderadores, no? Ese requisito de tener puntuación de 5 en la nueva etiqueta lo complica todo...

Comment: @wimi ese requisito lo imposibilita del todo, de allí que la gestión de la ontología acabe haciéndose a base de peticiones a los moderadores en Meta. Lo cual no me parece mal, ojo, pues así hay más transparencia en el proceso.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' bueno, el proceso estándar también es transparente y democrático, en el sentido de que 4 personas tienen que votar para que se acepte el sinónimo. Como siempre, el problema es que todos esos procesos están diseñados para los sitios grandes, y no funcionan en sitios con relativamente poca participación como el nuestro. Pero sí, en los sitios pequeños está bien que la aplicación de estas decisiones pase por los moderadores. Esperemos que pronto tengamos al menos dos, para que no sea siempre Charlie el que tiene que hacer todas estas cosas.

Comment: @wimi incluso en [SO] yo he tenido sugerencias de sinónimo paradas cuatro años, pues no hay suficiente gente mirándolo y con capacidad de votar. [Veo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) sugerencias ¡incluso de 2012! Creo que el debate en Meta es un mal menor, pues se "aseguran" más ojos que los de la gente que visita la página de sinónimos. Basta tener cuatro votos rápidos para crear el sinónimo, mientras que en Meta el debate suele ser algo más largo. En cualquier caso, es un sistema actualmente roto que hace tiempo que debería replantearse.

Comment: @wimi uy veo que editaste tu comentario. Sobre lo de _Esperemos que pronto tengamos al menos dos, para que no sea siempre Charlie el que tiene que hacer todas estas cosas_, matizar que prácticamente todos los sinónimos existentes los creé yo :P Recomiendo por cierto seguir [Tag Housekeeping Requests](/q/2962/1674), allí se hizo buen trabajo, ahora está bastante parado. Y ojalá algún día se complete [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](/q/2495/1674), hace falta que haya más gente pendiente del tema para buscar soluciones.

Comment: Pregunta: las traducciones que propones, ¿son todas iguales que las que hay en Stack Overflow en español? ¿O algunas son diferentes/nuevas? Diría que tiene sentido que las meta-etiquetas tengan los mismos nombres en los dos sitios.

Comment: @wimi creo que cogí las mismas. Lo que funcionó bien en MetaSOes fue crear una respuesta wiki donde las dos-tres personas interesadas fuimos perfilando sugerencias hasta estar bastante de acuerdo. Los dos sitios podrían estar mucho más hermanados, está en manos de los usuarios pues SE no ha establecido ningún vínculo especial entre ellos. Compartimos algunos usuarios, así que todo es cuestión de intentarlo.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' para hacer una prueba, acabo de traducir la etiqueta [status-reproduced] (que no tiene preguntas) a [estado-reproducido] . La etiqueta traducida ya no aparece en rojo, lo cual es mala señal. Puedes probar a añadir la etiqueta [estado-reproducido] a esta pregunta, a ver si te deja? Si te deja, quiere decir que la traducción le ha hecho perder el estatus de "moderator-only".

Comment: @wimi me dejó usarla. En su momento deduje que hay un "job" periódico que hace este mapeo, de ahí que el color (y la restricción a moderadores) no sean automáticos. Pero no tengo confirmación oficial, no sé si es verdaderamente el caso.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' esperemos 24 horas o así entonces. Si mañana sigue sin ser roja, me veré obligado a [status-deferred] esa parte de la propuesta... No sé si una [feature-request] en Meta sobre esto atraerá mucha atención.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Aha! Ahora es roja. Puedes probar a añadirla otra vez?

Comment: @wimi obviamente no ahora https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV8pv.png

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' gracias por la ayuda! He traducido todas las etiquetas "moderator-only", y parece que ya se han vuelto rojas. Ahora puedo añadir aquí la etiqueta [estado-completado] sin que parezca irónico. Si encuentras algún nuevo "bug" con las etiquetas traducidas, me alegraré si me informas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabo de traducir todas las etiquetas de la lista (espero no haberme dejado ninguna), usando las traducciones que has propuesto excepto las siguientes (pocas), que he traducido de manera algo distinta para hacerlas iguales a [las equivalentes en Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name):

- [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close) -> [votos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/votos-de-cierre)
- [vote-to-reopen](/questions/tagged/vote-to-reopen) -> [votos-de-reapertura](/questions/tagged/votos-de-reapertura)
- [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons) -> [motivos-de-cierre](/questions/tagged/motivos-de-cierre)
- [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) -> [perfil](/questions/tagged/perfil)
- [deleted-questions](/questions/tagged/deleted-questions) -> [eliminación-de-preguntas](/questions/tagged/eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-preguntas)

Espero que eso esté bien: si alguna os molesta especialmente, la podemos cambiar a una versión más "nuestra".

Comment: Excelente trabajo, gracias. Las [status-*] también requieren traducción, pero una vez traducidas dan problemas ([ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3495/83), que no está resuelto).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' hmm sí, me daba algo más de miedo jugar con las "etiquetas especiales" por si rompía algo. Aunque si el problema es solo que aparecen demasiadas preguntas en "Hot Meta posts", no es un gran problema. Qué hacemos, las cambiamos o las dejamos hasta que resuelvan el problema?

Comment: Hay otros temas (véase [esta pregunta de Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354929/209901) y las que enlazo yo en mi comentario allí). Como veáis, yo sí las traduciría todas por mantener la integridad de todo en el mismo idioma.

Comment: Veo que tenemos [meta-tag:idioma-del-post], creada hace tiempo. Creo que sería mejor que fuera [meta-tag:idioma-de-la-publicación] por aquello de usar las palabras en castellano.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Hecho!

Comment: Tremenda rapidez, muchas gracias