# Some of our tags on Meta are still in English

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, meta

I noticed this when the tag [election](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election) showed up recently. I think it is policy to  have tags on the main site in Spanish.

[Shall we switch to Spanish-language tags?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/shall-we-switch-to-spanish-language-tags)

There are not very many to re-tag in this case and I am happy to do that but I thought I would ask. I am not going to do any other re-tagging unless I am 100% sure I know the correct translation but in this case it is obvious.

Comment: There is no need to retag, right? We create the tag in Spanish and then makr the English tag a synonym of the Spanish tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas de Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/traduzcamos-toda-la-lista-de-etiquetas-predeterminadas-de-meta)

Comment: @wimi I was trying to avoid having synonyms because, as I understand it, this would put a heavy load on our diamond moderator.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I have no idea how I missed that one. I thought I had read all the posts tagged [tag:etiquetas} before I posted. I see that I am suggesting something slightly different though since I wanted to avoid synonyms.

Comment: Mmm why avoiding synonyms? If we just retag to Spanish, the English versions will be lost. This way, if someone decided to tag [tags], the system wouldn't know about it and we will end up having two separated tags. That's why I think that adding synonyms English <-> Spanish helps users in both languages and allows having all the info grouped by the same concept. This is what we have in the main site, also. The tool for mods makes it quite straight forward, it is just a couple of clicks where you check the "source" tag and the "target" tag, and you can also specify if you want the synonym.

Comment: If we had our full complement of mods @fedorqui'SOstopharming' then I agree but I was trying to avoid any extra work for Charlie.

Comment: @mdewey maybe it's time you run for moderator, I am sure you would be a very mindful, positive, and skilled one!

Comment: My almost complete failure to learn how to write Spanish disqualifies me I am afraid @fedorqui'SOstopharming' but thanks for the vote of confidence. I shall continue on the review queues instead.

Comment: @mdewey I think having a moderator that defends the interests of users that are less fluent in Spanish would be a good thing. (But this is just my opinion).

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate of [the other question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/24236), as I have almost completed this job (except, ironically, moderator-only tags such as [status-completed], which seem like they might break a couple of things if they are translated. See comments on my answer there).

Comment: @wimi thanks, I agree this is no longer live.

Comment: @mdewey (suggestions about new tags that need translation are still always welcome as comments on the other answer or as any other way to catch my attention. If not sure about how to translate, also as Meta questions).