# Mi presentación como moderador

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Desde ayer por la noche soy moderador en Spanish Language Stack Exchange. Esto ha ocurrido algo [más rápido de lo que esperaba](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/24236), lo cual parece que ha generado cierto descontento. Espero que ese descontento esté más dirigido a la manera en que se desarrolló el proceso de elección y menos a mí como moderador. Yo por mi parte intentaré hacer el mejor trabajo posible para llevar adelante esta comunidad.

Sobre mí: soy un español (de Madrid) que, como tantos otros, ha emigrado a Alemania. Hablo español, inglés, alemán e italiano, y esto ha despertado mi entusiasmo por las lenguas. Este es un entusiasmo "de tiempo libre": mis estudios y trabajo son en el campo de la ingeniería. Me gusta mucho la filosofía de Stack Exchange de concentrarse en producir contenido de calidad y no salirse del tema en el sitio principal. Los problemas que han ocurrido en el último año entre la empresa y la comunidad me gustan menos, pero quiero ser optimista y trabajar mirando más al futuro que al pasado.

Hablando de trabajar, empiezo ya mismo a cumplir las dos promesas que hice durante el periodo de nominación. En primer lugar, como SE no proporciona canales privados de comunicación, he creado una dirección de correo electrónico en la que me podéis contactar para temas relacionados con el sitio o la moderación que no sean apropiados para discutirlos públicamente. Podéis ver esta dirección en [mi perfil](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/24236/wimi?tab=profile).

En segundo lugar, empezaré esta tarde con la traducción de las etiquetas de Meta que faltan, de acuerdo con [esta propuesta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/24236). Parece que la propuesta ha sido bien recibida, pero si alguna de las traducciones propuestas no os gusta, podéis escribirlo en un comentario o respuesta a esa pregunta, para que podamos discutir alternativas.

Espero que vengan, poco a poco, tiempos mejores para la comunidad.

Comment: ¡Éxito! Seguro que harás una gran labor.

Comment: Enhorabuena. Te deseo suerte wimi en esta experiencia como moderador.