# Issue preventing proposing [expresiones] tag as a synonym of [modismos]

Tags: bug, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Given [expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression) is a synonym of [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) (and this [previous meta decision](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/deber%c3%adamos-juntar-modismos-frases-idiom%c3%a1ticas-expresiones-en-una-%c3%banica-etiq) to synonymise such tags), I tried to propose [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones) as a synonym of it as well.

However I got the following error message:

[image]

It seems that [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) had previously been proposed as a synonym of [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) before its merge with [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones), and this proposal has persisted behind the scenes, blocking the reverse association now.

This bug has been noted a few times before: [Tag synonym for 'edit', 'edits' and 'editing'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212662/tag-synonym-for-edit-edits-and-editing)

Can this be resolved (as per the actions in the above SE Meta post), i.e:

- Reverse synonym [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) → [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) and merge
- Add synonym [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones) → [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) and merge?

Answer (score 2):

The UI of Tag synonyms is a bit poor, so there are always some subtleties to take into account. In this case, the situation seems to be like this:

- [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones) is already a synonym target for two other tags: [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) and [fixed-expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expression), as seen in ['expresiones' Tag Synonyms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/expresiones/synonyms).
- The synonym creation does not allow suggesting a new mapping (A -> B) if the source (A) already has some tags pointing to it. That is, if A->B already exists, you cannot do B->C unless you remove A->B.

For this, the solution would be to:

- Remove the synonyms [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n) and [fixed-expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expression) from [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones).
- Create the synonyms [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n), [fixed-expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expression) and [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones) pointing to [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos).
- After a while, merge. Not instantly, since a merge cannot be rollbacked.

By the way, some mapping are not necessary: as seen in the [Tags list](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags) we now have [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones), [expresiones-fijas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones-fijas), [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n), [expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression), [fixed-expression](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expression), and [fixed-expressions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-expressions). There is no need to have all the tuples singular-plural, since they share a big part of the initial characters and user interface suggests tags based on the characters you type and match the beginning of the tags' names.

See [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/209901) in Meta.SE for more info.