# ¿Por qué tenemos [solicitud-de-modismo] pero no [solicitud-de-expresión]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Según tengo entendido, un [modismo](https://dle.rae.es/modismo) es una

> expresión [...] cuyo significado no se deduce de las palabras que la forman.

Por tanto, tenemos la etiqueta [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) y la etiqueta [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones), ambas con muchas preguntas. Sin embargo, cuando se trata de solicitar, solo tenemos [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo) pero no [solicitud-de-expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-expresi%c3%b3n). A veces (por ejemplo en mi última pregunta), el OP está buscando simplemente una expresión corta para decir algo, sin necesidad de que cumpla el requisito de que "su significado no se pueda deducir de las palabras que la forman". Ahí no parece encajar ni [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%c3%a9rmino) ni [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo).

Una opción extrema sería renombrar [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo) a [solicitud-de-expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-expresi%c3%b3n), dado que "modismo" es un subconjunto de "expresión". Pero esto sería probablemente contraproducente, porque muchas preguntas claramente buscan un modismo ([ejemplo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35539/24236)).

Pero, incluso sin la necesidad de deshacernos de [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo), ¿deberíamos tener una etiqueta [solicitud-de-expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-expresi%c3%b3n)?

Comment: Of course one could ask what is the difference between [tag:modismo] and [tag:solicitud-de-modismo]. If there is one it escapes me so I would eliminate the longer one. I agree having three tags is aesthetically unpleasing so we should have two or four.

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente, no añadiría más etiquetas. El uso que hacemos de las que tenemos es bastante inconsistente y solo conviene poner nuevas si alguien va a estar pendiente de "hacer cumplir". Ya la propia [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo) es poco conocido, como se ve en el hecho de que se haya usado 57 veces pero que haya 102 con [`[traducción]` y `[modismos]` pero sin esta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%C3%B3n+modismos+-solicitud-de-modismo).

Yo creé [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo) [en su día](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17723/1674) a imagen y semejanza de lo que se estila en [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags):

[image]

El debate sobre si deberían juntarse [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos) y [expresiones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones) está pendiente de resolución. En [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) escribí en referencia a unir etiquetas:

> Bloque de frases idiomáticas, aquellas que tienen un significado diferente del literal:
>
> - [modismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modismos)
> - [frases-idiomaticas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frases-idiomaticas)
> - [expresion](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresion)
> - [idiomatico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatico)
> - [expresiones-fijas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresiones-fijas)
>
> <sub>En [¿Es lo mismo un modismo que una frase idiomática? ¿Y una expresión fija?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17650/1674) vimos que modismo, frase idiomática y expresión idiomática son lo mismo.</sub>
>
> <sub>Posteriormente, en [¿Deberíamos juntar modismos / frases idiomáticas / expresiones en una única etiqueta? Should we use a unique tag for idioms?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/1674) resolvimos juntar todas menos [expresión](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expresi%c3%b3n).</sub>

Cuando se resuelva, se podrá meter mano a [Issue preventing proposing [expresiones] tag as a synonym of [modismos]](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4330/1674)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he descubierto algo nuevo hoy :D. "resolvimos juntar todas menos [expresión]". hmmm por lo que veo en [esa pregunta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2531/24236), todos querían juntar todas (incluyendo [expresión]) excepto un usuario (con 0 votos), que quería dejar fuera [expresión]...

Comment: @wimi sí, el tema quedó parado allí. La respuesta de Charlie apoyaba la opción de juntar, así en general, y eso hice. Como que el otro usuario expuso la objeción a hacerlo con [tag:modismos], la dejé fuera a la espera de tener más opiniones y ver si sí o no. Al no haber más, quedó así y no quise hacerlo unilateralmente. Si bien son cosas diferentes, su uso en el sitio es prácticamente indistinto, por lo que bien podrían juntarse.Y con ello esta pregunta también quedaría resuelta.