# In Meta, tag links with non-English characters do not work

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas, formato

Here in Spanish Language Meta we are unable to use `[tag:XX]` to refer to tags with non-English characters:

- [españa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1a)
- [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada)
- [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%c3%a9rmino)

While others do work:

- [colombia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colombia)

Could it be fixed? Our language contains many of these and the `[tag:XX]` syntax is very useful here in Meta when we are discussing about tags (for example [here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674)).

<sub>This has been [reported in Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281747/209901) but as a feature-request, but it works in other sites ([see it in French](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/631/10449)) so I do think that this is a bug.</sub>

Comment: I think this came up before, but I can't find reference to it now.  I think the thing to do is to get the attention of an SE employee who can fix it, [as was done on the main site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242397/165502).

Comment: @Flimzy [I did it in Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281747/209901) and Marc Gravell commented on it, but never came back with an update. I added a bounty to draw attention and still nothing, so let's see if Oded sees this post (I think he keeps track of bugs in all Meta sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a per-site setting that tells whether non-ASCII characters are supposed to appear in tags or not, it was (mistakenly) set to "no" in this site. Fixed now: [pingüino-español-monísimo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping%c3%bcino-espa%c3%b1ol-mon%c3%adsimo)

Comment: Great one, Konamiman! Thanks a bunch : ) I see I have to update the posts with some random edit to have the tags rendered.

Comment: If it's a small amount of posts, I can "rebake" them myself, just tell me the urls

Comment: No problem. It was just [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) and I already did that because it also needed removing now unnecessary links.