# ¿Deberían "jerga" y "coloquialismos" ser etiquetas sinónimas?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Acabo de fijarme que tenemos la etiqueta [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) y la [coloquialismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloquialismos). La primera con 94 preguntas, la segunda con 60 y un total de 11 [con ambas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga+coloquialismos).

¿Y si las juntamos?

Entiendo que coloquialismo se usa en el sentido de [coloquial](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9qTM1me):

> 2. adj. Propio de una conversación informal y distendida. Expresión, tono, estilo coloquial.

Mientras que [jerga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MQ2t2nA) usa:

> 1. f. Lenguaje especial y no formal que usan entre sí los individuos de ciertas profesiones y oficios.

Y no en:

> 2. f. Lenguaje especial utilizado originalmente con propósitos crípticos por determinados grupos, que a veces se extiende al uso general; p. ej., la jerga de los maleantes.

Y, de hecho, me parece que más bien la usamos como traducción de *slang*, que para mí siempre tiene una connotación de informalidad.

A mí me parecen bastante sinónimas así como las tenemos. ¿Y a vosotros? ¿Sería coherente juntarlas o más bien definir muy bien su ámbito de acción y ajustar su uso a lo que realmente quieren decir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En [¿Qué hacemos con las etiquetas “jerga” y “coloquialismos”? Vota una opción](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2565/1674) se sometió este tema a votación entre el 4 y el 13 de enero de 2017.

Estas eran las opciones y -en negrita- sus votos recibidos:

- **+1 -1** juntar [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) y [coloquialismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloquialismos).
- **+2** cambiar la definición de [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) para que se refiera a *lenguaje usado en contextos especiales*.
- **+2** hacer que [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) sea sinónima de [vocabulario-técnico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico), de modo que esta última sea la principal. Además, las preguntas de este tipo siempre llevarán esta etiqueta y, opcionalmente, una del campo al que se refieren (medicina, informática...).

Como veis, hubo empate entre la 2ª y 3ª opción. Dado que yo mismo publiqué las respuestas a mi propia pregunta-encuesta, no pude emitir voto (no se pueden votar las publicaciones de uno). Indiqué bajo una de las opciones que esa era mi preferida y resultó ser una de las que recibió dos votos. Por tanto, entiendo que ese voto mío rompe el empate y por consiguiente...

### La ganadora es:

> **hacer que [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) sea sinónima de [vocabulario-técnico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico), de modo que esta última sea la principal. Además, las preguntas de este tipo siempre llevarán esta etiqueta y, opcionalmente, una del campo al que se refieren (medicina, informática...).**

Ahora tocará crear este sinónimo, no sin antes revisar todas las preguntas en [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) para ver si encajan con la nueva definición.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez lo que deberíamos hacer es reconducir la etiqueta [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) al uso que copias del diccionario; es decir, a lenguaje usado en contextos especiales. Si lo hacemos así, ambas etiquetas marcarán cosas distintas y serán útiles. Si no, es cierto que la frontera entre argot (o jerga) y coloquialismo es bastante difusa; parece que una palabra que aparece como jerga pasa a considerarse simple coloquialismo cuando pasa un tiempo suficiente.

Comment: Actualmente tenemos etiquetas específicas del tipo [vocabulario técnico](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%C3%A9cnico) y [vocabulario médico](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-m%C3%A9dico), así como otras como [informática], [música], etc. El miedo que tengo es que si definimos [jerga] como lo que es, el argot, sea una etiqueta demasiado genérica que acabemos añadiendo siempre que se solicita una palabra de un campo determinado.

Comment: Entonces estoy de acuerdo contigo: la etiqueta *jerga* no hace nada útil y podemos fusionarla con *coloquialismo*.

Comment: They are clearly distinct meanings and useful terms but I suspect they are not used as scrupulously as they might be by posters on this site so fusing them seems a good idea.

Comment: El único problema que se me ocurre es que todas las jergas específicas de ciertos sectores se quedarán sin etiqueta, y no sería práctico crear una etiqueta para cada sector que la necesite, pues serían docenas. Quizás se podría dejar ese papel a la nombrada vocabulario técnico.

Comment: @mdewey it would be great if a bunch of avid users could handle retagging for some time until the difference is clear. What would be bad is to do all the effort and then see that it gets messed up again when we relaxed. Still, I don't know what is best.

Comment: @Nox esta es una buena idea, tal vez hacer [jerga] sinónimo de [vocabulario-técnico], renombrar [vocabulario-médico] a [medicina] y así saber que [vocabulario-técnico] es para preguntas de jerga de un ámbito profesional. Si además resulta que es una pregunta para médicos, pues se le añadiría también [medicina]. De esta forma nos aseguraríamos que todas las preguntas de jerga al menos estarían agrupadas en algo fácil de distinguir.

Comment: @fedorqui when people have had a bit more time to think why not create two or more answers just containing the options and let people up-vote one or more with which they agree? Having said that majority community voting does not always have the result you expect as 2016 has proved in a number of countries.

Comment: @mdewey this is an excellent idea, I will do this in few days, after enough people have gone through the post. Regarding voting... well, let's just hope 2017 is better :)

Comment: @fedorqui and mdewey What's all this voting you guys are speaking about? Users's question voting? Sorry but I'm not totally accustomed to that type of SE "mechanics" yet. Also fedorqui, what exactly means to make the two tags synonim? I suppose that when an user will use one of those tags, the site will suggest the other one, but I'm not really sure. Maybe there are a specific SE site where I can read about it?

Comment: @Nox en Meta es común realizar encuestas de opinión publicando preguntas en las que se añaden distintas respuestas con diferentes opciones. La gente vota + o - para determinar con qué opción se queda y la "ganadora" es la respuesta que acaba con un mayor puntaje. Ve [un ejemplo](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/108/1674). En cuanto a los sinónimos, estás en lo correcto; echa una ojeada a [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/209901) si quieres leer más detalles.

Comment: @fedorqui ya veo, pues sí, parece lo mejor que se puede hacer.

Comment: @Nox ya lancé la pregunta: [¿Qué hacemos con las etiquetas “jerga” y “coloquialismos”? Vota una opción](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2565/1674).

Comment: Recibido y votada la respuesta pertinente :)

Comment: Respuesta añadida con los resultados de la votación.