# ¿Qué hacemos con las etiquetas "jerga" y "coloquialismos"?

Tags: discusión, sinónimos-de-etiquetas, etiquetas

En [¿Deberían “jerga” y “coloquialismos” ser etiquetas sinónimas?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2559/1674) planteé la situación de las etiquetas [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) y [coloquialismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloquialismos).

Mi planteamiento inicial era el de juntarlas, pero [Gorpik sugirió](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2561/1674) reconducir *jerga* a su significiado real (lenguaje utilizado en contextos especiales), para así evitar la confusión entre ellas.

Posteriormente surgió un interesante debate en los comentarios, del que surgieron algunas propuestas.

## Utilicemos el hecho de que en Meta los votos sirven para indicar si estamos o no de acuerdo con algo

Por tanto, para salir de dudas y consensuar una solución, pongo a continuación una respuesta para cada una de las opciones. En los próximos diez días (hasta el viernes 13 por la noche) podéis votar positivamente a aquello que os parezca bien o negativamente a lo que no. La respuesta que mayor puntuación tenga al cabo de ese tiempo será la que definirá lo que haremos.

## Votemos, pues entre las siguientes respuestas

- juntar [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) y [coloquialismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloquialismos).
- cambiar la definición de [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) para que se refiera a *lenguaje usado en contextos especiales*.
- hacer que [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) sea sinónima de [vocabulario-técnico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico), de modo que esta última sea la principal. Además, las preguntas de este tipo siempre llevarán esta etiqueta y, opcionalmente, una del campo al que se refieren (medicina, informática...).

En todos los casos será bueno al final del proceso revisar todas las preguntas con estas etiquetas para ajustarlas a lo que se decida.

Comment: Cuando hablamos de modificar la etiqueta `jerga`, cómo afecta eso a la etiqueta `jerga-internet`? Porque para mi más que "vocabulario técnico o específico" jerga es también "argot", incluído el lenguaje tipo [SMS y similar de internet](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19192/5481).

Comment: @Diego no recordaba que también tenemos `jerga-internet`. Para mí lo más escalable sería eliminarla y reetiquetar con `jerga`/`vocabulario-técnico` e `internet` o `informática`. Pero entiendo que lo prudente es ver cuál es el resultado de esta pregunta-votación para ver qué encaja mejor con la decisión tomada.

Comment: @Diego al final salió ganadora la opción de juntar `jerga` con `vocabulario-técnico`. ¿Qué te parece que hagamos? Yo optaría por quitarla y reetiquetar con `internet` (que no existe) y según el caso añadir o bien ``vocabulario-técnico` o bien `coloquialismos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voto por:

**Hacer que [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) sea sinónima de [vocabulario-técnico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario-t%c3%a9cnico), de modo que esta última sea la principal. Además, las preguntas de este tipo siempre llevarán esta etiqueta y, opcionalmente, una del campo al que se refieren (medicina, informática...).**

Comment: Yo voto por esta -no puedo hacer efectivo el voto por ser yo quien publicó la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Voto por:

**Cambiar la definición de [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) para que se refiera a *lenguaje usado en contextos especiales*.**

Answer (score 0):

Voto por:

**Juntar [jerga](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerga) y [coloquialismos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coloquialismos).**