# Juego o actividad para trabajar en el reetiquetado de preguntas

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, juegos

Hoy en el chat hablábamos de las etiquetas del sitio y de su uso y curioseando un poco me di cuenta de que existen algunas muy generales con muchas preguntas, y otras muy específicas usadas en muy pocas preguntas.

En este último caso, no hay duda de que hay preguntas que se han etiquetado sólo con las etiquetas generales, ya que, por ejemplo, ¿cómo puede ser que sólo haya [56 preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%C3%B3n) etiquetadas con [acentuación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acentuaci%c3%b3n)? Todos sabemos que la acentuación en castellano puede ser un quebradero de cabeza :)

Bueno, pues seguíamos entonces hablando en el chat de que quizás se podría plantear una actividad o juego de re-etiquetado, en el que se trabaje por usar las etiquetas más específicas en preguntas ya existentes.

Os pongo un ejemplo: en [esta pregunta reciente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23915/why-say-dame-la-mano-instead-of-dame-tu-mano), la única etiqueta era [gramática](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica) (totalmente genérica), pero edité el *post* para añadir [artículos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art%c3%adculos) y [posesivos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/posesivos).

Así pues, de cara a llevar a cabo este juego o actividad, se señalaba que tendría la **contrapartida** de destacar en la página principal un montón de preguntas antiguas. Pero como **ventajas**, tendríamos las preguntas mejor clasificadas, lo que lleva a mejores criterios en las búsquedas, y además, probablemente con este trabajo de espeleología encontraríamos cosas interesantes que nos llevasen a abrir nuevas preguntas.

Así pues, tras esta hermosa parrafada, **ahí va la conclusión**: si os parece bien mi idea, proponed el formato de juego o actividad que se os ocurra en una respuesta, y entre todos podemos votar y comentar las mejores, y, llegado el caso, elegir e implantar una.

En cuanto a ***mi propuesta***, se basa un poco en la dinámica del Translation Golf: cada semana podemos proponer una **etiqueta de la semana** y trabajar todos por buscar y reetiquetar posts relacionados con la misma. Al final de la semana, el que más haya etiquetado (*correctamente*), puede proponer la etiqueta de la siguiente semana. Y también le podemos dar un [gallifante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juego_de_ni%C3%B1os_(programa_de_televisi%C3%B3n)).

Comment: ¡Me gusta la idea! ¡Quiero un gallifante! Creo importante que [ordenemos las etiquetas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) para que dadas dos preguntas similares, tengan las mismas. Esto actualmente no pasa y provoca  un cierto descontrol.

Comment: Lo malo va a ser que no vamos a tener manera de averiguar quién ha sido el que más preguntas ha reetiquetado. También corremos el riesgo de que la gente se emocione y reetiquete más preguntas de la cuenta, pero vamos, es un riesgo asumible. Más vale que sobren (etiquetas) que no que falten. Me gusta la idea, y una ventaja adicional es que se repartirán más medallas de etiquetas, que ahora mismo son difíciles de conseguir.

Comment: ¿Los cambios de etiquetas no cuentan como ediciones de un post y se pueden consultar? Si no, o si sí también, a lo mejor podemos crear un *post* por edición del juego (como el TG) y que cada persona que reetiquete algo ponga una respuesta al *post* y enlace las preguntas que ha reetiquetado, y luego se hace recuento. Igual es un poco arduo, pero creo que es algo asumible para los usuarios habituales.

Answer (score 1):

Es una propuesta muy interesante.  Hace poco surgió una pregunta acerca del uso de "le" (que no tenía nada que ver con el "leísmo").  Me pareció haber visto una pregunta parecida hace un par de semanas o meses, pero por más que busqué, no logré encontrarla.

Creo que se plantean preguntas redundantes en el ámbito del aprendizaje con frecuencia.  Sería útil tener buena etiquetación para poder cerrar las preguntas redundantes, y enlazarlas con las originales.

Para lograr esto, creo que lo siguiente nos ayudaría a entrelazar y hacer más útil el sitio:

1. Agregar etiquetas existentes a preguntas existentes (como propone Alicia aquí).
2. Crear más etiquetas sobre problemas comunes enfrentados en el aprendizaje del español, como por ejemplo **ser-estar,** **le** (del tipo *le digo a mi hijo*), la **omisión del sujeto** y cómo evitar la confusión, **se** (que será un gran dolor de cabeza).  Crear más etiquetas para ciertas áreas de vocabulario y expresiones, por ejemplo **amor** (ej. Cómo le digo a alguien que me intereso en lo romántico sin caer en lo vulgar), **familia** (Cómo se llama el esposo de mi cuñada), **diversidad** (esto incluye la orientación sexual, la raza, etc.).
3. Si hay varias preguntas sobre lo mismito, seleccionar la mejor pregunta con las mejores respuestas como pregunta canónica, y cerrar las otras, apuntando a la canónica, o por lo menos poner una nota "véase tal pregunta relacionada" con enlace.
4. Revisar las preguntas y respuestas que se contribuyeron en los primeros años del sitio y hacer un poco de limpieza. Si la pregunta está bien planteada, pero las respuestas existentes no llegan al nivel actual de calidad del sitio, pues se puede hacer una nueva respuesta, o se puede cerrar y apuntar a algo mejor hecho.  (Yo pienso que no es forzoso que la pregunta canónica sea la más antigua.)

Nota 1.  A veces un alumno del español explica exactamente dónde siente confusión, y creo que este tipo de pregunta hay que contestarla, a menos que de veras sea exactamente idéntica a otra pregunta.  Pero la respuesta sí puede apuntar a una respuesta canónica que servirá como referencia.

Nota 2. Creo que hay que distinguir entre dos niveles de explicaciones en las cuestiones de gramática.  A veces una explicación está súper rigurosa pero el OP no tiene el nivel de sofisticación todavía para entenderla así como se redactó.  Entonces en este caso quizás valdría la pena tener dos respuestas canónicas -- una súper completa, y una sencilla y quizás un poco subjetiva, diseñada para ayudar al alumno a entender más holísticamente, con un mínimo de términos técnicos.  No sé qué hacer con esto, porque las respuestas no llevan etiqueta propia....

Nota 3. ¿Cómo convertir este *spring cleaning* a un juego con competencia y premios?  Quizás el sistema que ya existe de los bounties y los badges nos serviría de alguna manera.  No sé.  No sé si habría que agregar encima de esto un nivel de puntuación adicional.

Nota 4. Si se acepta este reto de limpieza, sería bueno tener alguna manera de hacer *dibs* -- de indicar, "Yo voy a trabajar el tema ser-estar", para no duplicar esfuerzos.  Quizás con una respuesta comunitaria en Meta.

Nota 5. Les advierto que este tipo de limpieza lleva much tiempo, porque empiezas con dos preguntas parecidas y de pronto has encontrado diez.  Otra cosa -- es difícil a veces encontrar todo el material que trata sobre cierto elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una propuesta que creo que puede evitar que llenemos la *front-page* de "basura", limitando esta actividad a 5 preguntas diarias.

1. Una persona pone una pregunta en Meta enlazando a 5 preguntas del sitio principal cuyos tags deberían revisarse.
2. Los participantes revisan las preguntas, corrigen los tags, y responden en Meta enlazando a los historiales de sus revisiones.
3. La persona que puso la pregunta revisa las respuestas, y acepta la de quien más tags haya corregido (o mejor lo haya hecho, o menos haya tardado, eso ya...). Esto son 15 puntos de reputación en Meta, que ya es bastante premio por editar 5 tags :P
4. La persona "ganadora" tiene que proponer otras 5 preguntas para su revisión al día siguiente. Si no lo hace, se puede "desaceptar" su respuesta hasta que lo haga (esto sería opcional, por si se quiere fomentar que todos participemos por igual en la búsqueda de preguntas).

... y así hasta que nos cansemos, básicamente.

Se puede seguir aplicando lo de centrarnos en una etiqueta por semana (o por mes, que a 5 preguntas por día igual una semana da para poco).

Comment: ¿Es muy descabellado proponer que en vez de hacer las ediciones directamente, se propongan en el correspondiente hilo de Meta? Es decir: OP propone 5 hilos, y cada participante, propone los tags para cada uno de ellos. Luego por el propio sistema de votación de las respuestas en el hilo, se decide cuál es el mejor y es entonces cuando se lleva a cabo la edición (sea el OP o el ganador).

Comment: Y por cierto, a lo mejor es demasiado hacerlo todos los días (esto los fines de semana está desierto), ¿quizás podemos hacerlo cada 2 ó 3 días? O por ejemplo hacer edición de lunes, miércoles y viernes.

Comment: Los que se sientan seguros de los cambios que quieren hacer, que los hagan, sin discusión.  La discusión se puede hacer para propuestas más sustanciosas, creo yo.

Comment: @walen - Es que creo que SE ya nos da un sistema de incentivos, y sería mucho trabajo crear otro nivel de incentivización.  Y me gustaría minimizar la discusión que se lleva a cabo para cambios sencillos, para maximizar el efecto de nuestros esfuerzos de *spring cleaning*.