# Etiquetas "historia" y "etimología" -- ¿de veras son distintas?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, renombrar-etiquetas

Pregunta ejemplar: [¿Cuándo y cómo adquirió la palabra "follar" su acepción sexual?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23944/9385)

Sí, se pueden combinar las dos etiquetas  --> vota a favor (+1)

No, de veras hay que mantener [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) aparte de [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) --> vota en contra (-1)

Ahora mismo hay:

- 45 [preguntas con ambas etiquetas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia+etimolog%C3%ADa)
- 123 [preguntas con historia y no etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia+-etimolog%C3%ADa)
- 383 [preguntas con etimología y no historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%C3%ADa+-historia)

---

**Edit**: Parece que hay un claro consenso a no fusionar.  ¡Bravo, equipo!

Lo que se puede hacer ahora es chequear las definiciones, y más adelante la etiquetación de las preguntas (walen: "es cierto que no se están usando bien").

Eché un ojo a las definiciones.  Me molesta el sinónimo "etimologia" (sin acento) pero no encontré la manera de borrarlo.

Encontré mención de la evolución del idioma en la definición de "etimología", y también esta frase: "Origen de los términos y su desarrollo a lo largo de la historia".  Pero yo no soy la persona indicada para proponer edits a estas definiciones.

Yo pienso que si alguien tiene una idea clara como editar las definiciones -- y sobre todo, ***simplificarlas***, que lo haga por favor, y que nos avisen aquí para que los interesados puedan chequear cómo quedaron.

Quise poner nuevos sinónimos de "historia": *historia del idioma, history of the language, evolución del idioma, evolution of the language*.  Pero no pude porque no tengo reputación en esta categoría....

Comment: Más que iniciar la votación directamente (o _además de_), podría ser más útil definir cuál es su colisión y cómo desambiguarlas.

Comment: @walen lo que yo no entiendo es por qué no se crean dos respuestas CW (la pregunta no tiene por qué serlo) que correspondan con los votos "a favor" y "en contra", y que se voten esas respuestas. Luego las opiniones de cada uno pueden ser tanto ampliaciones de las respuestas, como comentarios a las mismas, como nuevas respuestas. Se podría poner un aviso pidiendo que se vote solo una de las dos respuestas CW, y siempre positivo (nunca negativo).

Comment: @walen - Según entiendo la cultura de SE, el formato que usé está bien, pero tú podrás eligir el otro formato para tus propuestas Meta si prefieres -- creo que ambos están bien vistos.  // Los votos de Meta no afectan la reputación en el sitio principal.  // Mi pregunta no es feature request sino un poco de housekeeping.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a explicar mi voto negativo: la etiqueta [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) se suele usar en preguntas acerca de la evolución de una palabra. Ejemplo: *[¿Por qué no existe una palabra escrita «hoder» (en vez de la versión con «j-»)?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23922/12637)* Esta pregunta no va sobre el origen de la palabra, eso el que pregunta lo tiene muy claro, sino sobre su evolución, y por eso tal vez no debería estar etiquetada como [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada). Tal vez la palabra "historia" no sea la mejor para las preguntas sobre la evolución del lenguaje (o sí), pero eso es otra cuestión. Tienes otro ejemplo en *[Conversión de "carillón" a "carrillón"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23721/12637)*, que pregunta sobre un punto concreto de la evolución de una palabra y no sobre su origen. Está etiquetada como [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) y no como [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada).

La pregunta que enlazas en tu ejemplo pregunta tanto el "cómo" del origen de la palabra (la parte de etimología) como el "cuándo" (la parte de historia).

Por otro lado, las preguntas sobre el origen de determinadas palabras o expresiones suelen estar etiquetadas como [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) pero no como [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia).

En todo caso, agradezco tu pregunta y la oportunidad que nos has dado de tener este debate.

Answer (score 2):

Voto en contra (con matices; ver abajo) porque no considero que se puedan fusionar, aunque es cierto que no se están usando bien.

Hay muchas preguntas sobre [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) del lenguaje que no tienen nada que ver con la [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) de palabras, como por ejemplo:

- [¿Desde cuándo tenemos las actuales reglas de acentuación?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/desde-cu%C3%A1ndo-tenemos-las-actuales-reglas-de-acentuaci%C3%B3n)
- [¿Cuál ha sido la evolución del abecedario español a lo largo del tiempo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18914/cu%C3%A1l-ha-sido-la-evoluci%C3%B3n-del-abecedario-espa%C3%B1ol-a-lo-largo-del-tiempo)
- [El sonido de la J de José, en la California española](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/el-sonido-de-la-j-de-jos%C3%A9-en-la-california-espa%C3%B1ola)

Y muchas más.

Por otra parte, es muy complicado explicar la etimología de una palabra sin explicar también su historia; y por eso, en multitud de ocasiones las preguntas sobre la [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) de una palabra se pueden entender también como preguntas sobre su historia.
Pero no siempre es así:

- [¿Cuál es la palabra del español con más etimologías diferentes admitidas por la RAE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22538/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-palabra-del-espa%C3%B1ol-con-m%C3%A1s-etimolog%C3%ADas-diferentes-admitidas-por-la)
- [¿Hay alguna relación entre cuerda (adjetivo) y cuerda (sustantivo)?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20406/hay-alguna-relaci%C3%B3n-entre-cuerda-adjetivo-y-cuerda-sustantivo)
- [¿Existen palabras con construcción similar a "penúltimo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/existen-palabras-con-construcci%C3%B3n-similar-a-pen%C3%BAltimo)

Por tanto, no creo que corresponda fusionar ambos tags, pues en principio se refieren a cosas diferentes, aun cuando pueda existir algo de solape.

---

No obstante lo anterior, es cierto que tenemos **un montón** de preguntas etiquetadas como [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) cuando en realidad versan sobre [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historia) del lenguaje:

- [Origin and usage of "¿" and "¡"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/137/origin-and-usage-of-and)
- [Why is "De nada" used as a response to "Gracias"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/why-is-de-nada-used-as-a-response-to-gracias)

Y viceversa, aunque en mucha menor medida:

- [Where does «estribor» come from?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21453/where-does-estribor-come-from) (*mea culpa*)

Sin duda es necesario darle un repaso al etiquetado de estas preguntas, y posiblemente ajustar las descripciones de los *tags* para orientar mejor a los usuarios.

Comment: Pues ya tenemos por donde empezar para el [Juego o actividad para trabajar en el reetiquetado de preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2778/1674).

Comment: Y sí, la descripción de [historia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/historia/info) y la de [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/etimolog%C3%ADa/info) (_Origen de los términos y su desarrollo a lo largo de la historia. The origins of terms and their development through history._) tienen cierta colisión. Probablemente podríamos usar la definición deda por el DLE de [_etimología_](http://dle.rae.es/?w=etimolog%C3%ADa): _Origen de las palabras, razón de su existencia, de su significación y de su forma._

Comment: Es interesante que [Origin and usage of "¿" and "¡"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/137/1674) aparezca como mal etiquetada, cuando la [wiki de etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/etimolog%C3%ADa/info) la menciona como ejemplo :D

Answer (score 1):

He cambiado el *excerpt* de [etimología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etimolog%c3%ada) para que diga:

> Origen de las palabras, razón de su existencia, de su significación y de su forma.

Que es como se define en el DLE: [*etimología*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H48BwrZ).

---

El sinónimo *etimologia* (sin tilde) parece que tiene cierto uso, pues se ha utilizado en un par de ocasiones ([fuente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms)). En todo caso, eliminarlo es apenas un clic para los moderadores.

---

El trabajo futuro está en utilizar bien estas etiquetas y corregir las que se usaron mal. Vayamos haciéndolo poco a poco, aprovechando para corregir otras cosas que puedan ser mejorables en las publicaciones.

Comment: ¿Se podría acortar un poco?  ¿Quizás "Origen de las palabras, razón de su existencia, significación y forma"?

Comment: Sugiere la edición, está en tu mano :)