# ¿Qué etiquetas deberíamos utilizar para las preguntas del tipo "Diferencia entre la palabra X y Y"?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

Veo la pregunta [What is the difference between "migas" and "migajas"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28842/1674), con etiquetas [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) y [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario) y me quedo dudando: ¿es correcto que use estas etiquetas?

Hago una búsqueda de preguntas similares [`is:q "difference between"`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=difference%20between%20is%3Aq) y me encuentro con unas cuantas:

- [Difference between "coche" and "carro"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11966/1674) [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) y [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones)
- [Difference between "a" and "de"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12326/1674) [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras)
- [Difference between "empezar" and "comenzar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4700/1674) [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras) y [sinónimos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos)
- [Difference between "oreja" and "oído"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1765/1674) [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras)
- [Difference between "oeste" and "occidente"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2548/1674) [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras)
- [Difference between "Luego" and "entonces"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12196/1674) [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) y [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras)
- [Difference between "mirar" and "ver"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12343/1674) [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras)
- [Difference between "Guardar" and "Conservar"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11982/1674) [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras) y [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras)

Parece pues que hay cierto lío en si usar [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) y [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras).

Charlie comentó en [su respuesta a *¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2530/1674):

> - Bloque de determinar qué palabra debe usarse para describir un concepto determinado: aquí veo varios bloques independientes. Por un lado, [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras) y [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%c3%a9rmino) implican elegir una palabra que mejor represente un concepto. Por otro, [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones) y [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado) sirven para aclarar mejor el concepto que representa una palabra. Por último, [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras), [terminología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminolog%c3%ada) y [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario) implicarían explicar las diferencias entre dos o más términos aparentemente similares, siendo la última etiqueta un poco más genérica y que podría implicar a otro tipo de preguntas, como las de aclarar un término.

Me parece un buen análisis, que nos llevaría a determinar que este tipo de preguntas que planteo usaran la etiqueta [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) solamente.

Eso sí, podría ser interesante determinar cuál es el linde entre [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras) y [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras). ¿En qué casos debemos usar las dos? ¿Qué otras etiquetas (tipo [sinónimos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos)) debemos utilizar en los tipos de pregunta "Difference between..."?

- Debatamos
- Decidamos
- Actualicemos los extractos de las etiquetas
- Reetiquetemos

Comment: ¿Y si creamos un etiqueta [tag:diferencia-palabras] o algo similar?

Comment: @blonfu eso hice finalmente! Gracias por la sugerencia, creo que [tag:diferencias-entre-palabras] funcionará bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es cierto que estas preguntas no buscan saber si usar un término u otro, o cómo usarlos, en un contexto concreto, sino solamente conocer las diferencias para poder distinguir a futuro cuándo usar cada cual. Eso excluiría [selección-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selecci%c3%b3n-de-palabras) y [uso-de-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uso-de-palabras) salvo en casos específicos.

Algunas de ellas, como la de "oeste vs. occidente", podrían cubrirse con [sinónimos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin%c3%b3nimos), pero otras como la de "a vs. de" no lo veo tan claro.

En realidad, estas preguntas lo que intentan es mejorar el conocimiento del vocabulario, conocer mejor el significado de dos palabras parecidas para poder emplearlas con más acierto. Valdrían entonces tanto [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario) como [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado) o [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones).

Aunque la pregunta que subyace en realidad es: ¿nos interesa tener identificadas de alguna manera estas preguntas que piden "diferencias entre" una palabra y otra?
De ser así, lo adecuado como propone blonfu sería crear un tag nuevo [diferencias-entre-palabras](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diferencias-entre-palabras) que permita localizar este tipo de preguntas rápidamente.
Si por el contrario no le vemos utilidad a crear una categoría para este tipo de preguntas, entonces los ya mencionados [vocabulario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulario), [significado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/significado), [definiciones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definiciones) deberían bastar.

Comment: Esto abre pues otro debate: ¿cómo diferenciamos [tag:vocabulario], [tag:significado] y [tag:definiciones]? Lo mismo podrían juntarse las dos últimas, como comentaba Charlie.

Comment: Siguiendo lo comentado aquí, ayer creé la etiqueta [tag:diferencias-entre-palabras]. Ahora será cuestión de ir reetiquetando. ¿Dejamos solamente esta etiqueta o mantenemos alguna? Creo que [tag:significado] ayudaría en este caso.

Comment: (nota: si usas `[tag:significado]` te crea un enlace a la página de la etiqueta)

Comment: Ya he empezado a reetiquetar. Unas cuantas al día, para no saturar. Te animo a unirte en la tarea!