# A question which is written in English is answered in Spanish

Tags: discusión, idioma-de-la-publicación

I want to know is it okay to answer a question in a different language?

I have seen in some websites that, for example, the OP is asking in English about the usage of a verb in Spanish; and one answer is completely Spanish!

Now, what if we encounter this problem in SE?

I think it is not good. I think we always have to assume the OP doesn't know the Spanish language; and that's why they are posting in English.

Comment: Related: [Mixed English/Spanish questions?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/68/13538). Note that sometimes, the answerer may not be proficient in/comfortable writing English.