# What should be in our FAQ?

Tags: discusión

> Please see the [new proposed FAQ](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/12)

I think it's time to begin discussing what should be in our official site FAQ.

Post each suggestion as a separate answer so the community can vote them up or down individually.  If extended discussion is needed on a specific item, please ask a separate Meta question to hammer out the details before the final version is added as an answer here.

Comment: Are we supposed to try to type up FAQ entries as they would ultimately appear, or just give suggestions about topics?

Comment: @jrdioko: Either is fine. Any suggestions we get that aren't suitable verbatim we will no doubt edit to fit the format of the FAQ. Thanks for asking!

Comment: If you want inspiration, [French L&U](http://french.stackexchange.com/faq) finally has an FAQ.

Answer (score 5):

We should probably mention that [questions and answers can be in either English or Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/mixed-english-spanish-questions), but the languages shouldn't be [arbitrarily mixed together](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/we-shouldnt-allow-questions-in-spanglish) and answers should try to follow the language used in the question, when possible.

Answer (score 5):

We should explain that [simple word translation questions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/are-word-translation-questions-on-topic) that could be answered by a dictionary are off-topic, but more complex questions about nuances in meaning or translation are fine.

Answer (score 4):

We should clearly specify the policy on [whether tags should be in English, Spanish or either language](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-tags-be-in-english-spanish-or-both). The consensus reached by that meta question was that they should be exclusively English except for the cases where there are no English equivalents.

Comment: Maybe this could be mentioned along with the other policies on language use in questions and answers. I don't know if it should have its own entry, since new users who would be reading a FAQ probably aren't involved in new tag creation quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

We should mention whether any type of culture (as opposed to language) question is allowed, and if so, which are on-topic.