# Dejo mi puesto como moderador

Tags: discusión, moderadores

Después de tres años de servicio, hoy he tomado la decisión de dejar mi puesto como moderador de Spanish Language Stack Exchange.

Accedí al puesto en 2020, en un momento en el que la participación en el sitio estaba decayendo ya sensiblemente. Una consecuencia de esto ha sido siempre la falta de candidatos suficientes para organizar elecciones competitivas a moderador, lo cual generó descontento en las dos elecciones que se han celebrado durante mi tiempo como moderador ([2020](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4397/24236) y [2022](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4463/24236)). A pesar de mi entusiasmo inicial, el problema de la baja participación se agudizó, y siempre fue difícil tomar decisiones porque cualquier encuesta en Meta no acumulaba más de 3 votos. A mí tampoco se me han ocurrido ideas para aumentar la participación, y en las segundas elecciones [dejé claro](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4447/moderator-election-interest-check#comment7238_4447) que me presentaba mayormente para mantener el sitio en funcionamiento.

Desgraciadamente, debido a esta baja participación y a otras razones privadas, mi motivación ha ido decayendo gradualmente, y llevaba algún tiempo pensando en dejar el puesto. La noticia de los [recientes despidos en Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393806/643262) ha acelerado mi decisión: si la compañía decide ahorrar el 28% de los salarios de sus empleados, estoy aún menos motivado a trabajar gratis para ellos.

Espero haber hecho un trabajo aceptable estos tres años, y también espero que haya suficientes candidatos en las próximas elecciones, que se encuentre un buen sucesor, y que vengan tiempos mejores para el sitio. Aunque mi participación como usuario normal también ha ido decayendo, espero seguir respondiendo algunas preguntas de vez en cuando.

Comment: We shall miss you wimi and your moderation and your answers on the site.

Comment: Gracias para tus esfuerzos. :) Nos puede decir que lo que pasa con los dos otros moderadores?

Comment: @Lambie la verdad es que no lo sé, pero está claro que las *flags* se están acumulando. Yo pedí el 22 de octubre que me quitaran el puesto de moderador pero no he recibido respuesta desde entonces.

Comment: Dime, a quien lo pediste? :) En esto se trata de informales, no de "pedir" Ves lo quiero decir? Este site se está poniendo cada vez peor...

Comment: @Lambie obviamente, lo que hice fue informarles, y justo después ponerme como inactivo. Cuánto tarden en quitarme el diamante no va a tener efecto en ninguna otra cosa...

Answer (score 3):

Muchas gracias, wimi, por tu trabajo todo este tiempo.

No es fácil ser moderador y te ha tocado un momento bajo en la historia de Spanish Stack Exchange: apenas hay participación y las decisiones de la empresa no ayudan a seguir "trabajando gratis para ellos", como bien dices.

Por ello, estar al pie del cañón durante todo este tiempo tiene mucho mérito y te tenemos que estar muy agradecidos por lo que has aportado, que no he podido seguir al detalle porque también yo estoy algo desconectado del sitio.

Ojalá el sitio tenga continuidad y espero que encuentres otros quehaceres que te llenen para seguir aportando a esta u otra comunidad (física o virtual).

Answer (score 0):

Well, So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish !

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, I mentioned in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), the main chatroom, that I had been away from Spanish Language Stack Exchange for a long time. Please excuse me.

I will not repeat what I said there other than sharing that I'm a moderator in Web Applications Stack Exchange and a native Spanish speaker from Monterrey, Mexico. I'm writing this answer in English because the official language is English. If I understand correctly, writing in Spanish is allowed due to *community consensus*. Please excuse me for not searching first<sup>1</sup>.

I'm happy that Wimi has replied to today's comments under the question.

The event that Wimi refers to that motivated their resignation as moderator is an event that caused commotion among the people who had to respond. Also, the Last Thursday was a significant holiday for the United States residents and people from other locations.

Please remember that Community Moderators are **volunteers**. If you haven't done so yet, please read [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

If pressing issues require immediate attention, please follow the guidance from [What if I need more help?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/more-help).

Tip: There is a link to the Contact form at the page footer of every Stack Exchange site, but it's better to use the link from the site related to the issue as it might include some context details like the user display name, among others.

I cannot guarantee that I will provide you with news soon. Despite any dissatisfaction or complaints you may have, please maintain a kind tone. This doesn't mean you should refrain from expressing dissatisfaction or complaining. I suggest we be careful and not unnecessarily use harmful words. To use a thoughtful tone, the writer should observe their mood. If anxious or angry, they still write a post using a word processor or keep it as a draft. Once you, the writer, are calm, they could review the post. Another option is to ask a friend to review the post before submitting it.

Notes:

1: I updated this post to include links to related posts, including the post about using English and Spanish on this Spanish Language Stack Exchange.

## Related

##### Local

- [Should we allow question and answer bodies to be written in Spanish?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/9624)
- [Histórico de moderadores de Spanish.SE / Timeline of Spanish.SE moderators](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3186/9624)

##### From Meta Stack Exchange

Meta Stack Exchange is where the bugs, feature requests, support and discussion about topics about the Stack Exchange Network take place. Sometimes, local issues are appropriately escalated to this site; other times, they are not.

- [Is it time for a SE Volunteer Labor Union or similar organization?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338316/289691)
  I posted an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394859/289691) a few days ago. I suggested that instead of creating a "Union", Stack Exchange *volunteers* and other users should look to join or create **local groups of users of digital services**.
- [Lack of Company follow-through / Company failure to meet expectations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394829/289691).
  A former employee created this post. Please read it and judge by yourself.
- [What's the action when a site has no moderation activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394838/289691).
  This post was created concerning the Spanish Language Stack Exchange situation related to this question.
- [Why are some Stack Exchange sites so inactive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394869/289691).
  I posted an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394870/289691) a few days ago. I mentioned that the lack of participation on Stack Exchange sites should be reviewed by-site. However, some events have affected multiple sites. Some of those events are referred to in Wikipedia's article about Stack Exchange.